# Como funciona a herança de construtor em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor

Em Java quando uma classe herda de outra é preciso inicializar o construtor da classe pai, certo? usando o `super()` e passando para este `super()` os parâmetros que o construtor do pai pede.

Exemplo de classe pai:

```
public class Pessoa{
    protected String nome;
    protected String dataNasc;

    public Pessoa(String a, String b){
        nome = a;
        dataNasc = b;
    }
}
```

Aqui o construtor pede duas *strings*, quero que uma classe herdeira desta tenha um construtor que recebe como parâmetros uma `String` e um `int`, sendo assim como eu inicializo o `super()`?

Essa é a classe herdeira:

```
public class Cliente extends Pessoa{

    protected String endereco;
    protected static int codigoCliente;


    public Cliente(String a, int b){
        endereco = a;
        codigoCliente = b;
    }

}
```

O construtor dela pede um `String` e um inteiro, fazendo isso:

```
public Cliente(String a, int b){
    super(a, b);
    endereco = a;
    codigoCliente = b;
}
```

Dá erro pois inicializei com tipos diferentes, minha solução foi essa:

```
public Cliente(String a, Integer b){
    super(a, b.toString());
    endereco = a;
    codigoCliente = b;
}
```

Existe outra forma de inicializar um construtor de um herdeiro que tenha que tenha parâmetros diferentes do construtor do pai?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso não faz sentido. O construtor de `Cliente` está recebendo, segundo você, um endereço e um código do cliente. Você não está recebendo um nome e uma data de nascimento. Você não pode pegar um endereço e jogar no nome, mesmo que eles sejam do mesmo tipo, nem um código e jogar na data de nascimento. O compilador pode não reclamar se os tipos forem compatíveis, mas não não significa que esteja certo. Ele não pode saber a semântica que você quer dar aos dados.

Então é lógico que é impossível você inicializar uma classe completa se você não tem todos os dados. Tem algumas alternativas dependendo do que você deseja.

A mais óbvia é pedir todos os dados necessários na classe `Cliente`:

```
public Cliente(int codigo, String nome, String endereco, Date dataNasc){
    super(nome, dataNasc);
    this.endereco = endereco;
    codigoCliente = codigo;
}
```

Note que se o nome do campo da classe bate com o do parâmetro eu posso fazer a desambiguação usando o `this` para mostrar que é o campo da instância da classe.

Note também que eu preferi receber a data de nascimento como um tipo `Date`, faz mais sentido. É óbvio que precisa mudar o tipo na classe `Pessoa` também.

Eu coloquei nomes mais significativos nos parâmetros. Aprenda programar para ficar fácil de entender o código.

Mudei a ordem dos parâmetros porque parece fazer mais sentido.

Mas se analisar mais a fundo verá que a organização destas classe faz menos sentido ainda. Se for um cliente tem um código mas se for outro tipo de pessoa não tem? Isto é estranho para mim. O mesmo vale para o endereço. Será que toda pessoa tem data de nascimento?

Outra mudança que eu faria é chamar o campo atualmente chamado de `codigoCliente` apenas de `codigo`. Se está na classe `Cliente`, é óbvio que é o código do cliente. O nome está redundante.

Também não faz sentido um dados que claramente é um campo de instância da classe ser declarado como `static`. Campos estáticos servem para valores únicos da classe por toda a aplicação, eles não estarão presentes em cada instância, em cada objeto, estará só na classe mesmo. É uma dado compartilhado por todos os objetos desta classe.

Nem falei sobre o [encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101). Isto é um problema mas foge do escopo da pergunta.

Uma outra possibilidade é deixar alguns dados sem preencher se isto for possível dentro do que você espera.

```
public Cliente(int codigo, String nome){
    super(nome, null);
    codigoCliente = codigo;
}
```

Não aconselho fazer isto mas é uma possibilidade. Desta forma você deixou tanto o endereço sem valor algum como a data de nascimento.

Eu faria assim:

```
public class Pessoa {
    protected String nome;
    protected Date nascimento;

    public Pessoa(String nome, Date nascimento){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.nascimento = nascimento;
    }
}

public class Cliente extends Pessoa{
    protected String endereco;
    protected int codigo;

    public Cliente(int codigo String nome, String endereco, Date nascimento) {
        super(nome, nascimento);
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ConstructorInheritance.java).

Você não precisa fazer assim, mas eu acho que esta forma está mais elegante. Ainda não perfeita, não quis mudar nada fundamental para o que você está tentando fazer.

[Pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Answer (score 9):

## Não misture as coisas

Você **não deve** passar qualquer coisa para o construtor da classe pai. Isso não tem tanto a ver com orientação a objetos.

Se a classe pai recebe um `nome` e uma `dataNasc` então a classe filha precisa receber esses valores além dos que ela mesmo já recebe.

A implementação correta, tanto tecnicamente como em termos de valores, ficaria assim:

```
public class Cliente extends Pessoa {

    protected String endereco;
    protected int codigoCliente;


    public Cliente(String a, String b, String c, int d) {
        super(a, b);
        endereco = c;
        codigoCliente = d;
    }

}
```

Em resumo, seu problema não é referente aos tipos, mas a quais valores são necessários.

Pense que a classes filha é uma extensão das classe pais, portanto os atributos são cumulativos.

## Não mexa com o que não entende

Remova o `static` do atributo `codigoCliente`. Isso faria o valor ser compartilhado entre todas as instâncias da classe.

## Evite confusão

Use nomes de parâmetros mais descritivos do que `a` ou `b`.  Talvez assim você não teria se confundido desde o início.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa {
    protected String nome;
    protected String dataNasc;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String dataNasc){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.dataNasc = dataNasc;
    }
}
```

E a classe `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente extends Pessoa{

    protected String endereco;
    protected int codigoCliente;


    public Cliente(String nome, String dataNasc, String endereco, int codigoCliente) {
        super(nome, dataNasc);
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
    }

}
```