# É correto criar um método construtor em uma classe abstrata?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor

Se uma classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada, criar um método construtor para essa classe abstrata pode ser considerada como uma boa prática ou não? Se sim, qual a razão para criarmos a implementação desse método?

Segue abaixo um trecho de código que ilustra minha pergunta:

```
public abstract class Funcionario {

    private String nome;
    private int numeroRegistro;

    public Funcionario(int numeroRegistro) {
        setNumeroRegistro(numeroRegistro);
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getNumeroRegistro() {
        return numeroRegistro;
    }

    public void setNumeroRegistro(int numeroRegistro) {
        this.numeroRegistro = numeroRegistro;
    }

    public abstract double obterSalarioBruto();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Funcionario [getNome()=" + getNome() + ", getNumeroRegistro()=" + getNumeroRegistro() + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Acredito que é desnecessário, a menos que você vai colocar valores nos atributos somente na classe pai, por exemplo, o que acho pouco provável.

Comment: Para esta pergunta não.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É correto, claro. A não ser que o [construtor não seja necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). E nem sempre é. Muito programador cria construtor sem necessidade. Outros deixam de criar quando "é obrigatório" ter.

Mas se a classe abstrata tem estados (normalmente tem) e eles precisam ser inicializados quando um objeto baseado nela (não por instanciação direta, claro, mas porque outra classe herdou dela) é criado, então o construtor precisa ser chamado, ainda que indiretamente através da classe filha.

Tem uma [pergunta sobre a chamada do construtor de uma classe superior por uma classe inferior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45699/101). Não faz diferença se a classe é abstrata ou não.

Obviamente que se a classe não possui estado, ou seja, variáveis internas, é pouco provável que um construtor seja necessário. Mas aí é outro problema, também não exclusivo de classes abstratas. E se a classe não tem estado, provavelmente ela deveria ser estática.

Evite chamar outros métodos dentro do construtor. Normalmente ele deve inicializar as variáveis diretamente. Dependendo do método chamado pode ser perigoso e colocar a instância em estado duvidoso ou quebrar a aplicação. Não quer dizer que esteja errado chamar os métodos, só tenha certeza que é o que deseja, muitas vezes a lógica da inicialização é diferente da lógica de atribuição. Este caso é a mesma coisa, então parece adequado usar o mesmo. Mas este é um caso oposto ao [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Agora o código faz o mesmo, depois há uma manutenção e eles passam fazer coisas diferentes. O código começa ter problemas porque foi conceitualmente mal concebido (claro que pode arrumar isso junto, mas pode esquecer que tem que fazê-lo). Note que estou no campo da hipótese, o caso concreto sempre deve ser avaliado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).