# É uma boa prática usar construtores (ou métodos mágicos) em interfaces?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface, construtor

Bem, geralmente venho utilizando interfaces para definir como alguns métodos serão utilizados.

Mas, para ser sincero, nunca vi ninguém utilizando interfaces para definir contratos para um `construtor`.

Em um caso específico utilizei para evitar a "reescrita" do construtor de maneira inadequada à uma funcionalidade de uma classe.

Exemplo:

```
class Colecao implements Colecionavel{

    public function __construct(array $items){
    }

    public function obterFiltrado(){
        return new static($this->aplicaFiltro());
    }
}



interface Colecionavel{     
    // Defino isso aqui, para não afetar a chamada `new static`
    public function __construct(array $items);
    // Faz o resto aí
}
```

Em alguns outros casos, já vi sendo utilizado uma interface que obriga a utilizar métodos mágicos.

Por exemplo:

```
  interface Stringable{
      public function __toString();
  }
```

Bem, considerando que construtores e métodos mágicos fazem parte "camada especial" da linguagem de programação, é uma boa prática utilizar interfaces para "obrigar" a classe a ter algum comportamento em relação a eles?

Comment: Existe isso de uma interface definir um construtor de uma classe? nem sabia...

Comment: @DiegoF observe isso http://ideone.com/LDJW0y

Comment: Não é uma boa prática, pois depende muito do contexto, a boa prática é saber encaixar isso de acordo com o contexto do projeto.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeiro quero repetir o que sempre digo: boa prática é fazer o certo para aquela situação. Então dizer que isso pode ou não pode fazer, para tudo, é uma má prática (com o perdão do trocadilho).

## Introdução

A maioria das linguagens não permitem isso já que elas optaram por ter um construtor com o nome da classe. Então se alguém fosse criar uma interface com um construtor nela, a interface só serviria para aquela classe, o que perderia seu sentido.

PHP optou por usar um nome genérico de construtor por algum motivo. Eu adoraria dizer que pensaram bem e chegaram à conclusão de que isso trataria benefício, mas não tenho tanta certeza (mentira, eu sei que foi feito nas coxas, foi só mais uma :) lamento quem se irrita com isso, mas não foi eu que escolhi fazer a linguagem assim, eu sou só o mensageiro).

PHP só permite ter um construtor. Pelo que entendi é justamente pelo fato de poder ter um contrato externo. Ou seja, trocaram um recurso interessante universal por outro de uso raro e polêmico. Isto é PHP!

E aí para solucionar essa questão sugerem o uso de métodos estáticos com nomes diferentes para criar múltiplos construtores. Bela gambiarra (não seria se não existisse construtor, seria uma decisão consciente).

## Problema quando se faz isso

Imagine o seguinte cenário: você quer fazer uma classe que implemente a interface `ITelefone` com o construtor `__construct(Telefone telefone)` e a `IEmail` com o `__construct(Email email)`. Já não dá. Ainda bem, porque não faria o menor sentido ter esses dois construtores. O certo seria ter um construtor `__construct(Telefone telefone, Email email)`. Agora imagine a quantidade de combinações que poderia ter se tiver várias propriedades.

Todos os casos onde vi mostrarem onde isso é útil o correto não é o uso da interface e sim de uma classe abstrata. Que seria a solução para o problema do parágrafo anterior.

## Ferramenta errada

A classe abstrata faz todo sentido. Um construtor deveria ter como única função a inicialização do objeto. Tem a ver com a estrutura do objeto. Quando se fala em estrutura, estamos falando em herança de classe. Quando se fala em interface se fala puramente em comportamento. Embora possa se dizer que o construtor define o comportamento da criação, ele é dependente da estrutura de forma direta.

Normalmente dizemos para [programar para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101). Mas o construtor tem a ver com a implementação, portanto faz pouco sentido colocá-lo na interface.

Alguns gostam de [simular contrato da estrutura na interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101) (definindo métodos que vão acessar atributos específicos). Isso é interessante, mas pode ser complicado fazer certo. Passa ser um problema do programador criar um construtor adequado para garantir a inicialização correta de todos <strike>atributos</strike> necessários para satisfazer todas interfaces que fazem isso.

Eu sou [crítico do uso de OOP em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101) em [várias perguntas que respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108227/101). Por motivos técnicos e também por motivos "político-sociais". A maioria dos programadores de PHP não entendem bem OOP e aplicam tudo errado. Se é para usar OOP que faça do jeito certo<sup>*</sup>.

## Solução

**[Se precisa definir um contrato para o construtor, faça em uma classe abstrata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89257/101)**. Inclusive pode fornecer uma implementação básica do construtor.

Se a linguagem não tivesse classe abstrata, ou mesmo herança real, aí **talvez** fizesse algum sentido usar a interface. Mas a interface estaria funcionando como classe abstrata sem implementação e sem estado.

Acabei de me dar conta de uma falha das linguagens que optaram por ter só interface. Algumas interfaces devem ser tratadas de forma especial sem auxílio da linguagem. Isso não é bom para uma linguagem que deseja robustez.

A título de curiosidade eu vejo um caso onde pode ser útil, ainda que não ache tão útil assim. Em vez de flexibilizar, pode usar a interface com construtor como limitador. Como a linguagem só permite um construtor, exigir um construtor vazio, por exemplo impediria a classe criar outros construtores. Além de achar isto uma má ideia quase sempre, o programador passa por cima só não implementando a interface na classe.

Nas minhas pesquisas eu vi algumas pessoas dizendo que isso poderia facilitar o uso do [padrão Factory](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101), mas não vi um exemplo demonstrando isso.

Mas se achar algum caso que a interface vai resolver de forma melhor, pode usar, só precisa ter certeza.

Entenda [para que serve um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) (vale para qualquer linguagem).

## Métodos mágicos

Aqui me parece fazer sentido, não sei se todos, teria que avaliar caso a caso, o `__toString()` certamente é ok. Eles são apenas comportamentos que a classe deve ter. A interface á para isso.

Leia mais [onde usar interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101).

<sup>*</sup>. Com o tempo eu andei mudando de opinião, eu acho que OOP é um sinal que as pessoas não precisam de PHP, a linguagem era boa quando não precisava disso, se precisa, adote uma linguagem que isso é feito da maneira correta e não uma gambiarra criada para sobreviver.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não sei se acha uma boa prática, mas depois de tanto tempo, acabei chegando a conclusão que eu também poderia optar por `final public function __construct(array $items)`. Como você não é a favor de usar o jargão das boas práticas para tudo, o que acha de fazer tal coisa nesse caso?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não tenho opinião formada pq o PHP tem algumas idiossincrasias e também porque não sei o que isto resolve.

Answer (score 11):

- Primeiro, gostaria de informar que o que estou para lhe repassar é somente a minha opinião, não tenho grandes referências para apontar aqui.
- Segundo, eu irei escrever os exemplos na linguagem C#, conheço PHP, mas prefiro não cometer gafes. Mas o importante é a ideia, estou bem ciente que o que vou lhe mostrar aqui você terá como simular com o PHP, que tem recursos para suprir a ideia apresentada.

### Antes de se perguntar o porquê, temos que entender qual o propósito de uma interface

Muitas linguagens de programação possuem um suporte para **POO (Programação Orientada a Objetos)**, que é uma das maneiras de se programar usando o **paradigma imperativo**, que possui uma ótima abstração para iniciantes aprender a programar. E o **POO** possui quatro pilares que devem ser respeitados para que a linguagem seja considerada como uma orientada a objetos:

- Abstração (eu pessoalmente acho que isso não é um pilar, mas sim uma base)
- Encapsulamento
- Herança
- Polimorfismo

O propósito das **interfaces** é justamente uma maneira de suprir a necessidade de um desses pilares, o **polimorfismo**. E o que é **polimorfismo**? **Polimorfismo** é a capacidade de algo assumir diferentes formas. Isso é muito importante para a criação de sistemas complexos, a habilidade de trocar mensagens entre os objetos de uma maneira que os comunicantes consigam conversar com o maior número de objetos diferentes nos ajuda a reaproveitar o maior número de código possível. O uso de polimorfismo nos permite um **baixo grau de acoplamento** e **alto grau de modularização**. Segue um exemplo:

```
public class Gmail
{
  public void Enviar() { /* envia um e-mail */ }
}

public class GerenciadorDeTarefas
{
  public void Finalizar(Tarefa tarefa)
  {
    tarefa.Status == EStatus.Concluido;
    this.Notificar();
  }

  private void Notificar()
  {
    new Gmail().Enviar();
  }
}
```

Aqui temos uma classe que é responsável por nos **Notificar** quando alguma **Tarefa** for concluída. Como uma notificação pode ser feita de diversas maneiras (SMS, Email, Tweets, Posts no Facebook, etc), nós encapsulamos o comportamento em um método privado **Notificar**. Atualmente o sistema trabalha somente com o envio de emails pelo gmail, mas se precisamos dar suporte para mais servidores? Aqui temos um problema, porque a classe **GerenciadorDeTarefas** está fortemente acoplada a classe **Gmail**, isso é, porque a classe **Gmail** possui um **baixo grau de polimorfismo**. Para resolver o problema, podemos fazer:

```
public interface IEmail
{
  void Enviar();
}

public class Gmail : IEmail { /* implementação */ }

public class GerenciadorDeTarefas
{
  private IEmail email;

  public GerenciadorDeTarefas(IEmail email)
  {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public void Finalizar(Tarefa tarefa) { /* implementação */ }

  private void Notificar()
  {
    this.email.Enviar();
  }
}
```

Dessa maneira nossa classe **GerenciadorDeTarefas** não possui mais a responsabilidade de conhecer para qual tipo de email será enviado as notificações. Agora ele sabe que somente conversa com um **IEmail**, não especificamente com o **Gmail**. Agora se eu quiser mandar emails com o **Yahoo**, **Hotmail** e etc, basta implementar a interface de **IEmail** e passar a classe que eu desejo usar no momento da construção do **GerenciadorDeTarefas**.

Note que eu tenho que remover as implementações concretas da minha classe de **GerenciadorDeTarefas** para que o desaclopamento seja real, aqui eu removi seguindo um dos princípios do **SOLID**, o **Dependency Inversion Principle (Princípio da Inversão de Controle)**, aplicando a técnica de **Constructor Injection**, existem várias outras técnicas, mas a mais simples é essa.

### Okay, entendi. Mas o que isso tem haver com a minha pergunta?

Note que para resolver o problema do uso do polimorfismo do **Gmail** eu precisei remover a chamada do construtor **Gmail** da classe **GerenciadorDeTarefas**? O **GerenciadorDeTarefas** não precisa em nenhum momento construir o atributo **email**, e nem deveria, isso não é uma responsabilidade mais da classe. Não adianta haver um atributo com alto grau de polimorfismo se eu precisar gerenciar na própria classe qual é o tipo concreto que ele vai usar. Eu já vi pessoas usando estratégias com **enums/strings** para resolver o problema, o que na verdade, não resolve o problema do acoplamento. Aqui está um exemplo de uma péssima "utilização" do polimorfismo:

```
public class GerenciadorDeTarefas()
{
  private IEmail email;

  public GerenciadorDeTarefas(ETipoEmail tipoDeEmail)
  {
    switch (tipoDeEmail)
    {
      case ETipoEmail.Gmail:
        this.email = new Gmail();
        break;
      case ETipoEmail.Yahoo:
        this.email = new Yahoo();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Por que isso é ruim? Porque toda vez que você implementar uma nova classe você precisará colocar ela dentro desse construtor. Agora se o seu código for uma biblioteca para terceiros, uma **DLL**, se o desenvolvedor que consome essa biblioteca precisar colocar um novo tipo de email, como ele fará isso? Ele não pode modificar o seu código, é uma **DLL**, ou seja, já era. NOTA: Tem maneiras de transformar uma **DLL** de volta no código original, mas isso é completamente inviável de se pedir para um desenvolvedor fazer para **extender** a sua biblioteca.

Agora se você realmente quer setar o tipo concreto na classe de uma maneira mais inteligente, uma abordagem no estilo abaixo seria mais interessante (nesse caso é completamente desnecessário usar herança para algo tão simples, eu acho que usar a técnica de **Constructor Injection** é mais simples e útil, mas está aí para conhecimento):

```
public abstract class GerenciadorDeTarefas
{
  protected IEmail email;

  public void Finalizar(Tarefa tarefa) { /* implementação */ }

  private void Notificar()
  {
    this.email.Enviar();
  }
}

public sealed class GerenciadorDeTarefasGmail : GerenciadorDeTarefas
{
  public GerenciadorDeTarefasGmail()
  {
    this.email = new Gmail();
  }
}

public sealed class GerenciadorDeTarefasYahoo : GerenciadorDeTarefas
{
  public GerenciadorDeTarefasYahoo()
  {
    this.email = new Yahoo();
  }
}
```

Dessa maneira quem consumir sua biblioteca pode extender a classe abstrata e setar o tipo concreto que ele quiser. Mas novamente, volto a dizer, nesse caso eu não acho viável fazer isso.

Agora chega o momento da primeira etapa da resposta: faz sentido definir um construtor na interface? Ele não ajuda em nada no polimorfismo, que é o propósito de uma interface. Então nesses cenários eu vejo que ele é completamente inútil.

### Existe um cenário eu vejo sentido usar (GENERICS):

**Generics** é o único caso que eu consigo pensar onde definir um construtor em uma interface seria um benefício para a questão do polimorfismo. Note que C# não possui suporte para isso, então será uma implementação somente teórica:

```
public interface IEmail
{
  IEmail(string message); /* __construct */
  void Enviar();
}

public class GerenciadorDeTarefas<TEmail>
  where TEmail : IEmail // Informa que o tipo genérico deve implementar IEmail
{
  public void Finalizar(Tarefa tarefa) { /* implementação */ }

  private void Notificar()
  {
    new TEmail("Tarefa concluída!").Enviar();
  }
}
```

Eu não vejo grandes problemas em um código desses. Alto grau de polimorfismo, fácil entendimento e definições de comportamento na interface. Claro, você está limitando a maneira que o email é criado, mas existe alguns cenários que isso é bem útil. A utilização também é bem prática, veja:

```
var gerenciadorDeTarefasComGmail = new GerenciadorDeTarefas<Gmail>();
gerenciadorDeTarefasComGmail.Finalizar(new Tarefa());

var gerenciadorDeTarefasComYahoo = new GerenciadorDeTarefas<Yahoo>();
gerenciadorDeTarefasComYahoo.Finalizar(new Tarefa());
```

Comment: Vou ser sincero: Vou analisar com calma quando chegar em casa... Parece que a resposta está bem completa :D

Comment: Completo realmente a resposta não está, se fosse falar de verdade sobre polimorfismo, teria que entrar em diversos tópicos, como linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, union type, duck type, mixins, traits, e etc. Mas tentei não sair do seu problema, que no caso é um problema mais relacionado com linguagens de tipagem estática. No caso de PHP, o pessoal conhece por Type Hinting. Mas qualquer dúvida, questionamento ou crítica, só comentar aqui. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Na minha concepção, o uso das interfaces é diretamente ligada ao comportamento e estrutura que se espera nas classes que à herdarão. Já os construtores, são apenas métodos executados no momento após o objeto ser alocado na memória, diria que eles estão mais ligados à instância e o tratamento do objeto do que o comportamento e a estrutura.

Um outro ponto que podemos analisar para chegar numa resposta para sua pergunta é que as interfaces muitas vezes vão ser herdadas por mais de uma classe, que por sua vez vão ter comportamentos diferentes. Vendo desse ponto de vista, especificar o construtor na interface pode limitar o uso da interface para futuras classes, dependendo de como for tratá-las.

Portanto, acredito que utilizar interfaces para (obrigar) os construtores terem uma ligação com ela diretamente não é uma boa prática. Já que ao meu ver, a interface (ou contrato como exemplificam) tem a função ligada ao comportamento, enquanto o construtor lida mais diretamente à uma especificação na hora de instanciar. Não vejo uma ligação coerente entre os dois que justifique o uso dessa prática.

Answer (score 6):

1. Interfaces não devem limitar e sim aplicar a capacidade das classes. Imagina que você tem algumas formas geométricas para calcular a área. Sabendo que cada forma tem um jeito diferente de se calcular sua área, você decide separar as formas em classes (Quadrado, Circulo...), depois adiciona um método area() para cada objeto que deve retornar a formula calculada da área.

Classe Quadrado

```
class Quadrado
{ 
     public function area()
     {
         return pow($this->largura,2);
     }
}
```

classe Circulo:

```
class Circulo
{
     public function area()
     {
         return pi() * pow($this->raio, 2);
     }
}
```

Feito isso decide iterar objetos dessas formas para ter a soma total de todas as áreas:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($formas as $forma){
    $total += $forma->area();
}
```

Caso um outro profissional necessite adicionar uma classe Triangulo, e por ventura não crie um método area.... Temos um problema, jamais o triangulo entraria para a soma acima. Nesse momento a Interface vem para nos salvar, com seu super poder de coação:

FormaInterface:

```
Interface FormaInterface
{
    public function area();
}
```

Com esse "contrato" dizemos que toda forma deve ter um método area, então devemos implementar nas nossas classes:

```
class Quadrado implements FormaInterface .....
class Triangulo implements FormaInterface .....
class Circulo implements FormaInterface .....
```

Feito isso podemos através de TypeHint receber apenas Objetos do mesmo tipo da Interface:

```
public function calculaAreas(FormaInterface $formas)
{
    foreach($formas as $forma){
        $this->total += $forma->area();
    }
}
```

O uso de uma interface deve se limitar apenas a esse tipo de uso.

2. Caso deseje bloquear a reescrita pelo construtor, pode defini-lo como private e através do getInstance definir que a classe será utilizada apenas de forma estática:

Construtor:

```
private static $instance;

private function __construct()
{
    // Sua inicialização 
}
public static function getInstance()
{
    if ( is_null( self::$instance ) )
    {
      self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

3. Sua classe Colecao não fica melhor assim?

:

```
Interface Colecionavel
{
    ... métodos pertinentes a um item colecionável.
}

class Colecao
{
    protected $itens;

    public function __construct(Colecionavel $itens)
    {
        $this->itens = $itens
    }

    // ... Métodos pertinentes a coleção
 }
```

Está em inglês, mas com uma forcinha da para entender tranquilamente a idéia: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

Answer (score 1):

A meu ver impor essa obrigação não é necessariamente errado. Depende do objetivo da interface em questão.

Se vc acha que todas as classes que herdarão aquela interface devem ser construídas de um certo modo, então defina o construtor na interface e vice-versa.

Simples assim.

Exemplo: vamos supor que vc quer definir uma interface para classes que tratarão uma lista de empregados. A interface servirá para várias listas de várias empresas com campos diferentes.
Essa interface só faz sentido se tiver uma lista para ser trabalhada. Então acredito ser correto definir o construtor obrigando a passar uma lista na interface.

Se por outro lado vc está definindo uma interface que pode ser expandida para calcular em listas ou em objetos passados a ela, faz mais sentido deixar a responsabilidade de desenvolver o construtor para quem implementar a interface.

Vc é que define que grau de liberdade é mais útil para quem for desenvolver a classe.

Answer (score 1):

Eu concordo em alguns pontos e discordo em outros nas respostas acima. Depende muito do caso que foi usado, se por exemplo todas as classes que forem implementar a interface precisarem de 2 parâmetros para serem inicializadas, por que não deixar contratado na interface que elas precisam de um construtor com 2 parâmetros?

Usemos outro exemplo de método mágico, que é o __toString. Digamos que eu queira uma série de classes para tratar texto, todas elas implementarão a interface TextoInterface. Seria errado eu contratar na interface a obrigatoriedade do método __toString(), uma vez que todas as classes devem possuir auto-cast para string?

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring