# É correto afirmar que o encapsulamento visa a coesão? Por que?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

Baseado na afirmativa abaixo, segue meu questionamento:

> *Coesão e Acoplamento são princípios de engenharia de software muito
>   utilizados. Quando queremos ter uma arquitetura madura e sustentável,
>   temos que levar em conta estes dois princípios, pois cada um deles tem
>   um propósito específico que visa melhorar o design do software. O que
>   acontece é que muitas pessoas não sabem a diferença entre eles e
>   acabam não conseguindo obter os benefícios que colocá-los em prática
>   na hora de se desenhar a arquitetura de um software.*

Fonte: [Entendendo Coesão e Acoplamento - DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-coesao-e-acoplamento/18538)

Quando estou na fase de arquitetura de software, baseando-se nas melhores práticas, quando eu consigo construir uma classe coesa e com baixo acoplamento, posso afirmar que o `encapsulamento` visa a `coesão`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, encapsulamento é uma técnica para obter a coesão, embora não a única. E o encapsulamento também tem seus próprios objetivos.

Obviamente que a tentativa de levar o encapsulamento a ferro e fogo pode prejudicar a coesão. Coesão é obter o equilíbrio. É comum vermos a tentativa de dar mais encapsulamento e por consequência acabar aumentando o acoplamento, baixando a coesão.

Certamente expor detalhes que não importam externamente vai contra o encapsulamento e deixa o componente menos coeso. E colocar detalhes que não dizem respeito ao objeto dentro dele está encapsulando e piorando a coesão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

[O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)