# Encapsulamento em PHP orientado a objetos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Tenho dois *models* `User` e `Post`.

Ao editar um *post*, quero saber se o usuário é o autor do *post* (o *post* tem um atributo `user_id`) para autorizar a edição.

Se eu tiver um método dentro da classe `Post` que recebe um objeto `User` para verificar se o `User` é o autor daquele `Post`, eu vou estar respeitando o paradigma de orientação a objeto?

Li que uma classe não deve depender de outra. Esta é a maneira certa de fazer?

Comment: Ao meu ver, o problema maior é passar um objeto inteiro se a única coisa que precisa é um número (id). Sugiro ler [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104340) pergunta antes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É difícil afirmar sem maiores detalhes. Teria que ver a implementação disso, como será usado e o que pode acontecer no futuro para tomar a decisão. Não sei nem se deveria receber um objeto `User`.

Se é o que deseja fazer, faça, e veja se isso é bom no futuro. E talvez descubra outra coisa que muitos não percebem: as pessoas fazem coisas para dar manutenção mais fácil depois, e gastam tempo pra fazer isso, e a manutenção nuca vem. O que mais vejo hoje em dia é sistema que praticamente não são evoluídos, aí adota-se uma complexidade para algo que não é usado.

#### OOP

Mas a primeira coisa que deve saber é que existem várias definições do que é orientação a objeto. E em todas o PHP se beneficia bem pouco desse paradigma porque ele é secundário (alguns dizem nem ser paradigma de fato), porque serve para organizar códigos complexos que se relacionam de forma complexa. PHP é uma linguagem de *script*, ela é praticamente um microsserviço inerente. Ela separa tanto as coisas que faz pouco sentido usar OOP nela. Mas ela começou permitir porque a indústria de forma geral é pouco informada de como as coisas funcionam e são guiadas muito por marketing, o que fez ela adotar a possibilidade de escrever código assim "pra não ficar de fora da moda".

Faz mais sentido se usar OOP em [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101), Java ou C#.

Mas posso dizer que não existe fórmula mágica para definir o que é certo para respeitar OOP. E se tiver, porque precisa respeitar se fizer algo que é adequado ao que precisa? Que problema isto causa? Tem que tomar a decisão porque algum problema é causado se fizer errado. Se não consegue definir se causa algum problema, não é porque é OOP que vai ajudar.

Entre essas controvérsias sobre o que é OOP há quem diga que tudo que diz respeito ao objeto deve estar dentro dele, isso é encapsulamento. Mas cada um tem uma visão do que é esse tudo. Há quem diga que se algo pode ficar de fora então deve ficar. Eu sou dessa turma. Ou seja, nada de encapsular o todo, mas encapsular o mínimo. A tal ponto que em alguns casos nem deveria ter uma classe. Muito menos com todos mecanismos que costumam usar.

Seja qual for a opção, sem dominar como modelar as coisas, sem muita experiência, sem ter **todas** as informações necessárias sobre o assunto, e geralmente não tem-se isso, a não ser que esteja fazendo algo que já fez antes e aprendeu muito com isto, potencialmente sairá errado.

Aprenda modelar e preocupe-se menos com OOP. Inclusive porque começaram usar o termo para duas ou mais coisas diferentes, aí quando está lendo algo não sabe para qual das versões de OOP estão falando. E claro, quem está falando aquilo diz que o dele é OOP, o resto é outra coisa. Muito do que dizem ser OOP é só modularização.

Eu percebo que as pessoas têm dificuldades de respeitar até questões gramaticais em português que usam o tempo todo (eu mesmo sou assim), imagina em algo que ela não usa sempre, porque a língua que a pessoa deve falar quando está programando é a do problema a ser resolvido, não é nem a linguagem de programação. As pessoas passam por muita dificuldade sobre taxonomia e ontologia ou mesmo dialética, então é complicado fazer certo e [saber que está certo mesmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Aí sai isto:

[image: Fiat 147 detonado andando pelas ruas]

Ou pior ainda em OOP acontece muito isto (e elas não percebem, principalmente em PHP):

[image: Carro velho enferrujado aos pedaços semienterrado]

Conceitos que devem ser dominados e que nada tem a ver (diretamente) com OOP: [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

E veja [É correto afirmar que o encapsulamento visa a coesão? Por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero, sua resposta me esclareceu muito, obrigado. "Principalmente esse parágrafo": Mas o que posso dizer é que não existe fórmula mágica para definir o que é certo para respeita OOP. E se tiver, porque precisa respeitar se fizer algo que é adequado ao que precisa? Que problema isto causa? Tem que tomar a decisão porque algum problema é causado se fizer errado. Se não consegue definir se causa alguma problema, não é porque é OOP que vai ajudar.

Comment: Como sempre alguém não gosta de ouvir que é PHP não é tudo isso, OOP não é tudo isso, e aí negativa. Como a pessoa não tem argumento ela não diz o porquê do negativo.

Comment: Eu (mesmo sendo iniciante) percebi que tem uns "puristas" da programação. Que tal linguagem é a melhor, tal tecnologia é a certa... Mas eu não caio nessa hehe

Comment: @Maniero sou um dos que negativou, não por discordar (até concordo), mas me parece que em toda a resposta os únicos parágrafos que tem uma relação direta com a pergunta são o 5° e 6° o resto (e maioria) da resposta é focada em falar que "PHP não é tudo isso, OOP não é tudo isso". Apesar dos links ajudarem bastante, também não são o que foi perguntado (pelo menos não se eu entendi a pergunta), senão a já teria sido marcada como duplicada

Comment: Eu sei, e sei o outro negativo também. Que bom que resolveu dizer o porquê do negativo e não concordo com ele porque você mesmo diz que foi respondido e está correto, negativar porque tem outras informações não me parece adequado, mas é um direito seu. Eu sei que você o faz pelas suas convicções, não foi como o outro que tem indícios de tendenciosidade.

Comment: @Maniero acho importante mencionar outros problemas na resposta, mas me parece que, fazendo isso, acabou desfocando do assunto da pergunta, talvez um parágrafo ou dois com links para outras respostas suas (tens várias opções) falando sobre o assunto seria suficiente. O meu negativo é pelo desfoque não pelo conteúdo extra

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam sim,entendi isso, mas **eu** acho que é injusto, mas pelo menos não é por perseguição, tá ok. Nos mantemos discordantes nisso e vida que segue, agradeço o comentário, de verdade, te respeito por isso.

Comment: @Jhonny agora você pode votar em tudo site também. Já viu o [tour]?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam acho que ele respondeu ao que era pertinente e o desfoque você deveria considerar com uma adicional relevante para algo que geralmente só pessoas com muito tempo de experiencia com isto vão entender, ou seja é pertinente, mesmo que você não entenda de primeira ;) ... não estou afirmando que esta inteiramente certo, mas acho que para ter certeza de tudo que foi falado ainda sim é necessário entender os problemas comuns neste tipo de situação tecnicamente, o que geralmente não se aprende/compreende em poucos meses, ao contrário, é necessário muita experiencia.