# Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos, terminologia

Estava lendo um livro sobre orientação a objetos e essas duas entidades são tradadas de modo diferente. Qual a diferença entre ambas?

Comment: A classe é um modelo/template o objeto é o modelo personalizado com valores ou estado.

Comment: @rray  obrigado camarada !! Você poderia responder a pergunta !!

Comment: essa pergunta fica interessante quando começamos a questionar o que é "programação orientada a objetos" e "programação orientada a classes".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Pensa como uma questão de uma construtora que precisa construir casas.

**Classe** é a planta, é o planejamento, é o modelo a ser seguido para que a casa seja construída dentro de certas características. É algo abstrato, é algo lógico. Lá está definido todos os elementos que a casa terá e as características básicas de como eles serão compostas. Ela só existe no código. Classe tipifica o que será modelado por ela. Ela determina os estados possíveis e os comportamentos que os objetos podem ter.

[image: Planta]

O **objeto** é a casa. É algo concreto, algo físico. Nele os elementos estão de fato presentes ali. É algo palpável (em termos de computador), é algo que pode ser manipulado. Ele existe na memória, durante a execução da aplicação. Objeto possui valores para os estados definidos e chamam os comportamentos definidos executando os algoritmos. Tem um tempo de vida transitório.

[image: Prédio]

Então o objeto é uma instância da classe. Na classe você pode dizer que aquele objeto terá uma cor, no objeto você diz qual é a cor, só pode dizer isso porque foi definido na classe que essa informação deve estar no objeto.

Ao contrário do que muitos acreditam um objeto não precisa ser criado com base em uma classe. Por exemplo um `int` não precisa de uma classe para defini-lo, mas ele ainda é um objeto quando instanciado (`1` é uma instância).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bem bolado, só para ilustrar um pouco mais. Agora pensa em um loteamento de varias casa iguais, aquelas que o governo da para o povo. Possui uma planta (`Classe`) em que todas as casas vao se basear, isso é, mesmo numero de quartos, mesmo numero de banheiro, etc. Os Objetos seria as casa prontas, cada casa possui um habitante diferente, moveis diferentes, ou seja possuem `atributos` diferentes. Resumindo todas as casas são iguais em suas estruturas, mas possuem elementros dentro diferente. Objetos de uma classe X são todos iguais, o que diferenciam são os valores atributos   que eles tem.

Comment: Tá + pra *array* :D `Casa[] cohab = new Casa[1000];`

Comment: hehehe, é que eu quiz dizer que apartir de uma classe, se faz varias instancias.

Comment: Na edição você colocou 3 links de imagem, mas só usou 2. Esqueceu da imagem [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJtc7.png) ou mudou de ideia e não removeu o link?

Comment: Acho que não removi o link, era pra ser só essas duas mesmo. Achei que o sistema faria isto.

Answer (score 19):

Interessante que apesar de ser uma pergunta trivial, quando estava aprendendo sobre orientação de objetos conversei com diversos programadores experientes e ninguém conseguiu me explicar, de maneira clara, o que é uma classe e o que é um objeto.

Só fui aprender e entender qual era a diferença quando comecei a programar e pude ver, na prática, o que era só teoria pra mim.

A classe é um modelo, um planejamento, tal como a maquete de uma casa. Essa casa tem diversas características que não estão expressas no modelo (classe) tais como cor, se é sobrado ou não, se tem garagem ou não, quando foi construída, qual o valor venal, qual a área construída, etc. Isso é classe.

O objeto seria a classe materializada, ou seja, um objeto com os devidos atributos **qualificados**: uma casa azul, térrea, com garagem, construída em 2015, com valor venal de $ 100.000,00, com área construída de 60m2, etc. Isso é objeto, também conhecida como instância da classe. A instância ocupa espaço na memória tal qual uma casa ocupa espaço em um terreno.

A mesma classe pode dar origem a vários objetos, todos são casas, mas cada uma terá características diferentes.

A mesma analogia pode ser aplicada com o conceito de composição. Uma classe pode ter um atributo que é uma outra classe. Por exemplo, a classe Casa pode ter um atributo chamado Seguro. Esse atributo Seguro é uma outra classe que tem os seus próprios atributos, tais como Seguradora, Indenização, Início de Vigência, etc.

Outra analogia pode ser feita com a herança. Uma casa pode estender uma classe chamada Edificação. Uma Casa é uma Edificação assim como um Iglu também o é. A classe Edificação tem seus atributos próprios, como Data de Construção, etc. Todos esses atributos fazem sentido para qualquer classe que estenda Edificação.

E o conceito de implementação (utilizado na linguagem Java, por exemplo). Uma casa pode implementar a interface Chaminé. Nesse caso, todas as casas que implementassem Chaminé seriam obrigadas, por exemplo, a dizer em qual local da casa será instalada a chaminé. Isso seria um método implementado da interface.

Comment: Estou com essa dúvida mesmo. Porém, essas respostas ajudaram bastante.

Comment: Na verdade a maquete seria um protótipo que também é usado em orientação a objeto, mas não é uma classe que funciona mesmo como uma planta.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma de explicar usando uma pessoa como exemplo

**Classe**

Regras(lógica), adjetivos(Atributos) e verbos(métodos).
Parte escrita, o arquivo em seu projeto.

**Objeto**

A pessoa em si(Instancia), João.
Dados que estão na memória e foram carregados na execução.

Lendo livros sobre Orientação objetos as vezes o autor escreve sobre uma Abstração nomeando(se referenciando) como um Objeto, isso confunde um pouco, na prática(código executando) o Objeto é o mesmo que instancia, nos livros 'as vezes' creio que o autor estava se referindo a uma classe, a parte escrita de fato e não ao objeto em memória(instancia).