# Utilizando $this em POO PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Não entendi muito bem o que o $this "pega".

No caso temos um código assim, por exemplo:

```
<?php
class Teste {
    public $testando;
    public function VamosTestar(){
       this->$testando = false; 
   }
}
```

No caso ali, o $this está "substituindo" o que? A class teste? Se eu fizer assim, vai ser a mesma coisa?

```
<?php
    class Teste {
        public $testando;
        public function VamosTestar(){
           Teste->testando = false; 
       }
    }
```

No caso, acho que não, pôs no meu NetBeans me retornou um erro. Mas o que eu usaria se não quisesse usar o $this?

Comment: O correto é `$this->testando = false;`, o this se refere a classe  neste exemplo.

Comment: Editado, falta de atenção minha. Mas por exemplo, se eu não quiser usar o "$this" eu posso usar o nome da class? Como?

Comment: Só para constar, isto `Teste->testando = false;` não funciona, deve entender primeiro o que é um "classe instanciada" e o que é "uma classe" ;)

Comment: Isso que estou na dúvida, Guilherme, obrigado por responder, vou poder pesquisar.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho de uma olhada [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/3635)

Answer (score 3):

> Utilize **`$this`** para fazer referência ao próprio objeto. Outra opção seria o **`self`**, mas este faz referência a própria classe. Simplificando, o `$this->variavel` é para métodos não estáticos, o `self::variavel` é para membros estáticos.

Um exemplo de uso do $this e do self.

```
class Foo {
    // Variável privada
    private $bar = 1;

    // Variável estática
    private static $fooBar = 2;

    function __construct() {
        // Imprime ambas variáveis
        echo $this->bar . ' ' . self::$fooBar;
    }

    // Caso tente imprimir $bar com self, receberá uma mensagem de erro
    // Caso tente imprimir $fooBar com this, receberá uma mensagem de erro
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente o `this` refere a propria classe.

Entenda da seguinte maneira:

```
class Teste {
    public $testando;
    public function VamosTestar(){
       $this->testando = false; 
       //estaClasse->testando ou Teste->testando
   }
}
```

`$this`: "Esta classe"

`testando` atributo com nome testando.

Para acessar funções da propria classe ou atributos da propria classe usamos a palavra resertada `$this`, o `$this` também pode ser usado para acessar funções e atributos herdados de outra classe como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Pai {
    public $nome;
}

class Filho extends Pai {
    public function foo(){
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

Utilização:

```
$filho = new Filho();
$filho->foo();
```

o `$this` procurara o atributo `$nome` desde a primeira class estendida até a classe atual.;

Comment: Então, sempre terá que usar o $this, no caso. Só pra eu entender de vez.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho, sim se você quiser acessar funções ou atributos da propria classe onde está o de classes estendidas você precisa usar o `$this`, muitas linguagens de programação utilizam este conceito com o `this`

Comment: Não da pra eu não usar. Ou eu poderia usar $nome->nome?

Comment: Estou meio confuso com isso ainda, tenho que estudar mais :| Mas obrigado pelas respostas!!!

Comment: O que você ainda esta com duvida? se quiser inclua na pergunta que você fez editando ela que com certeza alguém te ajudara.