# Como saber se há conteúdo num objeto da classe?

Tags: c#, objetos

Preciso saber se tenho conteúdo numa classe ou se ela está vazia, como consigo essa informação?

```
Classe usuario = new Classe();
```

Queria poder consultar se há conteúdo nessa minha classe `usuario`. Em Delphi há algo como `Count` por exemplo.

Comment: Olhando para ela?

Comment: Que pretendes saber métodos, propriedades ?

Comment: Classe é um protótipo. Você não sabe nada à respeito dela até ela ser instanciada em um Objeto. Para entender o porquê que sua questão não faz sentido, considere "classe" como a planta baixa de uma casa e você que saber se tem alguém na sala sendo que a casa nem foi construída ainda...

Comment: Desculpe, ainda sou iniciante, mas modifiquei a questão para ver se ajuda.

Comment: Pode verificar se o objecto foi instanciado verificando se é diferente de null

Comment: `usuario != null` ????

Comment: @DeividSouza você quer saber se há conteúdo em alguma propriedade do objeto?

Comment: O jean, jorge e Maniero responderam minha questão, mas vou colocar uma pergunta na resposta do @Maniero pois testei e não funcionou como esperava com lista. Agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos definir as coisas direito. O que deseja é saber se tem conteúdo no objeto e não na classe. [Classe é só um modelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Você pode verificar se o objeto está nulo:

```
if (usuario == null)
```

Fora isto depende do objeto. Pode ser que o objeto tenha conteúdo seja vazio, porém não nulo, mas depende da semântica do objeto para saber como verificar isto.

Por exemplo, você dizer que tenha uma classe `Usuario` com uma propriedade chamada `Ativo` que é `bool` pode verificar:

```
if (usuario.Ativo)
```

Se for um *array* ou uma lista (qualquer enumerável) é possível usar o `Count` que está querendo:

```
if (lista.Count() > 0)
```

partindo do princípio que sabe que `lista` não é nula, caso contrário seria melhor:

```
if (lista != null && lista.Count > 0)
```

Mas é quase certo que um `Usuario` não é uma lista, e e se for, tem algo muito errado aí.

Se for uma `string` pode ser que funcione uma verificação se é diferente de vazio:

```
if (texto != "")
```

ou

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/HasData.cs).

Primeiro precisa saber com o que está lidando para depois achar uma solução.

Embora os métodos sejam diferentes, em essência é igual ao Delphi. Não existe solução universal.

Comment: Eu acho que o AP esta querendo saber se há valores nas propriedades do objeto do tipo da classe. Talvez eu possa ter interpretado mal a questão dele, mas parece ser isso.

Comment: Pode ser, mas aí só ele pra afirmar.

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu precisava, novamente desculpe por expressar mal, a falta de conhecimento atrapalha um pouco rs. Testei por classe e funcionou, testei por lista `if (lista.Count > 0)` e ele me dá o seguinte retorno: `O operador ">" não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos "grupo de métodos" e "int"`. Obs: Minha lista tenho utilizado com Task.

Comment: @DeividSouza eu tinha esquecido dos parenteses.

Comment: Enfim, `Classe` e `Lista` com Task deram certo agora, agradeço.