# Onde devo instanciar os objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes

Em POO há certo grau de teoria e de boas práticas para escrever as classes e as interfaces.

Elas ficam dentro de pastas com nomenclaturas consagradas. O nome da classe deve ser idêntico ao nome do arquivo. A classe deve ser precedida pelo comando `package` que coincide com a estrutura de pastas da própria classe.

Mas parece que não há teoria sobre como os objetos devem ser escritos e arquitetados.

É isso mesmo? Fica a gosto do programador?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Elas ficam dentro de pastas com nomenclaturas consagradas. O nome da classe deve ser idêntico ao nome do arquivo.

Não, programação orientada a objeto nada tem a ver com isso, e não prega qualquer coisa nesse sentido. É um mito que deve ter lido em algum lugar escrito por alguém que não entende do assunto, ou então interpretou algo equivocadamente.

> A classe deve ser precedida pelo comando package que coincide com a estrutura de pastas da própria classe et cetera.

Talvez esteja falando de Java, mas isso é específico da tecnologia.

> Mas parece que não há teoria sobre como os objetos devem ser escritos e arquitetados.
>
> É isso mesmo? Fica a gosto do programador?

Não é gosto do programador, é necessidade. O programador deve entender o problema como um todo e montar o que é necessário do jeito que é necessário. E isso só é possível com muita experiência. Que só se adquire errando, fazendo vários projetos, participando de equipes com gente bem capacitada (o que é raro), vendo os erros dos outros e melhorando o seu entendimento. Tem que sempre estar com a cabeça aberta pra ver coisas novas. O que é um pouco problemático hoje em dia porque as pessoas querem tudo rápido, pulam etapas e não adquirem a base necessária para pensar por si própria. Aí ela procura fórmulas mágicas para parecer que está fazendo certo.

Tem um monte de confusão de conceitos na pergunta. [Objetos não são escritos, classes são escritas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Arquitetura é algo muito mais amplo que isto.

Objetos devem ser instanciados onde eles são necessários, nem antes, e obviamente nunca depois. Espero que entenda do que está falando, caso contrário, volte algumas casas no tabuleiro para aprender esses conceitos antes. Não use nomes de coisas que não sabe do que se trata. O conhecimento se constrói um conceito bem entendido de cada vez e nunca pula para um conceito que exige o entendimento de suas dependências.