# Instâncias e variáveis no C#

Tags: c#, .net, classes, variáveis

No C# quando você cria uma variável você cria um valor de determinado tipo, por exemplo uma `bool` só pode receber `true` ou `false`, uma `int` números inteiros e por aí vai...

Queria saber como seriam classificados esses valores, `true`, `false`, `2`, `2.5f`...

Eles podem ser classificados como instâncias ou objetos?

Uma instância é um valor que é uma cópia do valor original com algumas alterações?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, esses dados descritos são instâncias ou objetos, tudo que é guardado na memória durante a execução é uma instância de um tipo, é um dado concreto baseado em algum modelo que pode ser simples ou complexo, nesses casos são bem simples, são dados que o processador reconhece, mas todos ocupam espaço em memória. Mesmo um `true` (que no fundo é um número 1 armazenado) é uma instância.

Se isso não é uma instância, é o que então? Por que seria diferente? Tenha sempre em mente o que eu já respondi em pergunta anterior que [objetos são apenas a concretude de um modelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101), não importa qual é este modelo, pode ser um número muito simples de 1 byte ou alguns poucos bytes que o processador entende, ou algo mais complexo que envolva várias partes.

E instâncias nem precisam estar associadas à [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), valores podem existir e, claro, estarem armazenados na memória sem precisarem ter um nome vinculado à este endereço de memória onde o valor está.

A instância é o objeto, e só isso, não tem nada cópia, de valor original, de alteração, nada disso.

É uma instância, não importa se o tipo é por valor ou por referência. Então esses valores todos são objetos (instâncias) iguais aos objetos criados com base em classes, o que muda é a forma de acesso e eventualmente o local onde o objeto é armazenado. Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101). Os tipos por valor geralmente (mas não obrigatoriamente) são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e isso significa que qualquer alteração que tente se fazer nele obriga criar um instância. Os tipos por referência podem ser, caso de `string`, mas geralmente não são. Também: [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Também pode ser útil ver [Como uma "struct" é organizada na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183287/101). Esses tipos que estão exemplificados na pergunta são como `structs`.

```
var i = 1;
```

gera uma instância do tipo `int` (tem 4 bytes, sendo um dele o sinal) e a ordem deles depende de arquitetura) e ela é armazenada na memória, no caso na *stack*, porque é uma variável local.

```
class Exemplo {
    private int i = 1;
}
```

Agora é armazenado dentro de outro objeto e que será armazenado no *heap* já que o objeto *container* é uma classe. Pelo menos até agora é assim, há indícios que no futuro algumas classes poderão ser alocadas na *stack* como otimização. Nesse caso há uma instância de `int` que está dentro de uma instância de `Exemplo` quando esta for criada em algum ponto do código. Todas as classes e estruturas criadas com código C# são compostas por uma ou mais instâncias de algum tipo. Assim:

```
var e = new Exemplo();
Write(e.i); //acessando a instância de `i` dentro da instância `e`.
```

E ainda podemos colocar uma instância de um `int` no *heap*:

```
object i = 1;
```

Neste caso `1` é um valor inteiro que será armazenado dentro de um objeto do tipo `object` e que por ser uma classe estará no *heap*. Você não consegue acessar esse valor sem um *cast* porque `object` não sabe como acessar um valor, ele originalmente não deve ter valor algum. Quando faz o *cast* apenas está acessando a instância já criada, ele não cria, converte ou altera nada:

```
Write((int)i);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Cast/Simple.cs).

Isso é um *unboxing*, mas é irrelevante para a pergunta.

Mais:

- [Onde devo instanciar os objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318922/101)
- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Qual a diferença em instanciar, inicializar e declarar uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/101)
- [Como uma classe é organizada na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101)
- [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101)
- [Diferença entre tipo primitivo e objeto em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274391/101)
- [Conceito de classe, entidade e objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203166/101)

Comment: Ok... deixa eu ver se entendi... uma instância é transformar um modelo em algo para uso, por exemplo: public class Exemplo { int a public void Simples () { } } isso é um modelo para criação de instâncias, sendo que uma instância é o modelo sendo utilizado, como por exemplo, private Exemplo EX, EX é o que será utilizado e Exemplo é simplesmente um modelo para criação, então instâncias são os modelos sendo utilizados. Agora acertei?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Note que a outra resposta se apega a um conceito errado. Algumas pessoas aprendem programar só orientada a objeto (que é um conceito mal definido, pesquise aqui mesmo) e OOP prega que só é objeto o que foi criado por uma classe, e só fala em instâncias dessa forma, aí o pessoal mistura conceitos abstratos com concretos, ignorar a real implementação das linguagens e acabam cometendo erros, honestos, mas ainda são erros. Pra sua pergunta o que você comentou agora, este exemplo pouco importa, sua pergunta são em cima dos tipos básicos que nem tem classes formalmente definidas.

Comment: A forma mais fácil de aprender orientação a objetos é _não_ usar uma linguagem com esses recursos. Recriar a _ideia_ de OO usando structs e functions em C torna mais fácil de ser entendido, na minha opinião. Feito isso, fica fácil de entender que a declaração de uma classe simples é basicamente um syntax sugar. Além disso, o programador aprende a amar o garbage collector (quem vai direto pra Java e C# não sabe o quão FABULOSO é não ter que se preocupar com gerenciamento de memória).

Comment: @Gabriel perfeito em tudo!

Comment: @Gatti é uma forma de ver sim. Não é algo tão simples, mas ajuda entender. Este modelo pode estar implícito.

Comment: Ok... instâncias são um modelo sendo utilizados, variáveis são estruturas que podem armazenar determinadas instâncias, dependendo do seu tipo (bool armazena true ou false, int armazena números inteiros, decimal números decimais etc...), então quer dizer a programação orientada a objetos consiste em criar e usar instâncias, acertei?

Comment: OOP é muito mais complexo que isto, e não, criar e usar instâncias você pode em qualquer paradigma.

Comment: Mas a parte que instâncias são modelos sendo utilizados e que variáveis podem armazenar instâncias está certa, não?

Comment: Sim, eu já falei que sim, de forma simplificada é isso. Você precisa entender o melhor o Stack Overflow. Isto é uma site de Perguntas e Respostas, não é um fórum. Você faz uma pergunta pergunta e recebe uma resposta, não é para ficar tendo uma discussão extensiva. Depois de obter respostas você pode aceitar uma delas para indicar para outras pessoas que resolveu o que queria saber. E pode votar nessa e outras respostas, do site todo, isto ajuda classificar as respostas. Você pode aprender muita coisa lendo os melhores *posts* do site. E votando neles conforme te ajuda.

Comment: Você conhece algum fórum que fale sobre C# e que respondam rápido

Comment: Mais rápido que aqui? Não. Com maior qualidade que aqui? Não. O que você precisa é procurar uma forma estruturada de aprender, ir conceito por conceito, começar realmente do começo, de antes dos detalhes que quer saber, para construir conhecimento, não aprender receitas de bolo. tentando aprender em fóruns não dá certo, dá para tirar dúvidas apenas. Aqui tem muita coisa pra dúvidas, aprender a usar as ferramentas ajuda também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50. Não ignorar o que as pessoas falam para você também ajuda.