# Como imprimo o nome de uma instância em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

```
class Panzer():
   def __init__(self):
      self.life = 100
      self.blin = 100

drogo = Panzer()
cabal = Panzer()
sirius = Panzer()

group = [drogo, cabal, sirius]
for i in group:
print()
```

O que eu devo colocar no `print()` pra obter a saída:

```
drogo
cabal
sirius
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Não faz e não precisa fazer.

Você quer imprimir o nome da variável, e isso você sabe qual é até certo ponto. Qual seria a vantagem de imprimir o nome de algo que já está no código? E mais, pra que serviria para o usuário saber o nome da variável que aquele objeto está lá? Não faz sentido para seu código e não faz sentido para o usuário. Talvez esteja lhe faltando entender [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) e [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101). Também pode ser útil: [Instâncias e variáveis no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/338603/101)

Quando o objeto é usado em outro lugar que não seja uma variável nomeada como fez na lista, aí obviamente não não tem como imprimir algo que não existe.

Vou escrever um código que tem **exatamente** o mesmo resultado (na verdade as variáveis são completamente redundantes e desnecessárias), me fala onde está o nome:

```
group = [Panzer(), Panzer(), Panzer()]
```

Instâncias (objetos) não possuem nomes. Pode imprimir características internas deles, aí depende de cada objeto. Se precisa ter um nome nele precisa definir o objeto para ter um nome. Talvez queira algo assim:

```
class Panzer():
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      self.life = 100
      self.blin = 100

group = [Panzer("drogo"), Panzer("cabal"), Panzer("sirius")]
for i in group:
    print(i.name)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6DGsDT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wsfwnzsv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/Name.py).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo