# Manipulando polimorficamente subsclasses

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Como funciona a manipulação de subclasses pela superclasse?

Neste seguinte código, o `array` de uma classe, imprime os valores de outras classes.

## zoo.java

```
public class zoo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vaca mimosa = new Vaca();
    Gato bichano = new Gato();
    Carneiro barnabe = new Carneiro();

    Animal bichos[] = {mimosa, bichano, barnabe};

    for(Animal animal : bichos)
    {
            System.out.print(animal.nome + " é da classe " + animal.getClass().getName() + ", tem " + animal.numeroPatas + " patas e faz ");
            animal.som();
            System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

> As outras Classes:

## Animal.java

```
public abstract class Animal {
protected String nome;
protected int numeroPatas;

public abstract void som();

}
```

## Vaca.java

```
public class Vaca extends Animal {
public Vaca(){
    this.nome = "Mimosa";
    this.numeroPatas = 4;

}
@Override
public void som(){
    System.out.print("MUUUU");
}

}
```

## Gato.java

```
public class Gato extends Animal{
public Gato(){
    this.nome = "Bichano";
    this.numeroPatas = 4;

}
@Override
public void som(){
    System.out.print("MIAU");
}
}
```

## Carneiro.java

```
public class Carneiro extends Animal{
public Carneiro(){
    this.nome = "Banabé";
    this.numeroPatas = 4;

}

@Override
public void som(){
    System.out.print("BÉÉÉ");
}
}
```

Isso significa que a superClasse pode receber as subclasses?
não ficou muito claro para mim o que está ocorrendo no `foreach`.
Polimorfose é apenas quando varias subclasses tem ações diferentes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma geral a superclasse não deveria conhecer nada das subclasses. E de fato nesse código não ocorre.

O `foreach` está varrendo um *array* com objetos que possuem abstratamente um monte de `Animal`. Cada um deles tem uma característica própria concretamente, cada um é um animal específico. Por isso na hora de imprimir ele assume o comportamento do objeto específico. Ele não chamará o comportamento específico do `Animal`, e sim do `Gato`, da `Vaca`, etc., isso é o polimorfismo. Sem ele, tentaria chamar o comportamento do `Animal`, o que neste caso nem seria permitido por ele ser, acertadamente, abstrato (sem comportamento real).

Superclasse não recebe coisa alguma, ela é só um modelo para as outras classes, que é só um modelo para criar um objeto. Veja [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

O que está no objeto é que importa durante a execução. No momento que executa ele sabe qual é o tipo em questão e chama o método de acordo com o tipo, isso é resolvido dinamicamente. Se o método fosse `final`, ou seja, sem polimorfismo, o tipo declarado seria usado e chamaria o método da superclasse, o que é impossível neste caso.

Se terá várias ações diferentes ou não, é indiferente. [Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) é um comportamento sendo assumido pelo objeto de acordo com seu tipo concreto, nada mais que isto.

Comment: Será que escrevi algo errado aqui?

Answer (score 4):

Polimorfismo é a capacidade que um método tem de agir
de diferentes formas, dependendo do objeto
sobre o qual está sendo chamado.

Quando ocorre a chamada de um método, a
JVM decide qual método invocar
dependendo do objeto instanciado na
memória.

Você faz uma iteração em um array de animais chamando os métodos definidos na classe Animal, e que obrigatoriamente é sobrescrito pelas subclasses Gato, Carneiro etc. Quando, na iteração, for reconhecido pela JVM que aquele animal é um Gato, será chamado o método sobrescrito pelo Gato. Assim será para os demais Animais que contém no array.

Imagina que você tem uma coleção de carros: Fusion, Azera, Corola, Ferrari Enzo etc. Todos tem a ação de abrir porta, porém diferente dos outros carros a Ferrari Enzo abre a porta para cima. A ação de abrir portas é padrão para qualquer tipo de carro, porém o fabricante pode determinar a forma que será aberta. Quando você passar a coleção de carros em um foreach e chamar o método abrirPorta() de cada carro da coleção, será realizado o que cada fabricante determinou quando sobrescreveu o método abrirPorta(). O método invocado é determinado pelo tipo do objeto que está armazenado na memória.

```
Animal mimosa = new Vaca(); // Objeto Vaca
Animal bichano = new Gato(); // Objeto Gato
Animal barnabe = new Carneiro(); // Objeto Carneiro
```

Answer (score 1):

O polimorfismo, cujo conceito já foi explicado em outras respostas, pode ocorrer entre classes que tenham uma relação de "é-um", ou seja, que apresentam herança. No caso do seu exemplo, a classe `Vaca` "é um" `Animal` porque aquela estende (`extends`) esta. `Gato` e `Carneiro` seguem o mesmo modelo.

Uma das vantagens da herança é que você pode usar uma superclasse como argumento que sirva, ao mesmo tempo, para essa superclasse e também para todas as subclasses dela. Imagine que você precise criar um método que imite o som de cada bicho. Sem herança e polimorfismo, você teria algo assim:

```
private void imitarSom(Carneiro carneiro);
private void imitarSom(Gato gato);
private void imitarSom(Vaca vaca);
```

Para cada subclasse, um método diferente, com código muito parecido, enfim, uma solução ruim.

Em vez disso, por que não um método que receba uma superclasse como parâmetro?

```
private void imitarSom(Animal animal);
```

Pronto. Agora, você pode passar para esse método uma `Vaca`, um `Gato`, um `Carneiro` e seja lá qual outro bicho você crie no futuro, porque o método recebe um `Animal`. Lembra-se quando eu disse que herança é uma relação de "é-um"? Pois então, qualquer classe que "é um" `Animal` pode ir como parâmetro, e o polimorfismo dará conta.

É isso, então, que acontece no *array* e tem relação com a sua dúvida:

> Isso significa que a superClasse pode receber as subclasses?

Como você faz o `for` usando como argumento uma superclasse e nós sabemos que subclasses têm relação de "é-um" com ela, em tempo de execução o compilador polimorficamente acessa o método correspondente daquela classe filha sendo iterada naquele exato momento no `for`, imprimindo o valor correspondente.

```
Animal bichos[] = {mimosa, bichano, barnabe};

for(Animal animal : bichos) {
   System.out.print(animal.nome + " é da classe " + animal.getClass().getName() + ", tem " + animal.numeroPatas + " patas e faz ");
   animal.som();
   System.out.println();
}
```