# Herança em tempo de compilação?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, compilação

Estava revisando uns códigos e alguns conceitos quando encontro a seguinte assertiva:

> O mecanismo de herança em Java ocorre em tempo de compilação, ou seja,
>   todo reaproveitamento de código realizado por herança é imutável em
>   tempo de execução

Perdi um bom tempo tentando entender o conceito, mas confesso que não consegui entender, como assim imutável em tempo de execução? Está correto que herança em Java ocorre em tempo de compilação? Sempre pensei que era em tempo de execução.

Comment: Uma vez definida a herança no código, nem a JVM pode refazer essa relação. Então, quando executa, não muda; é "imutável" em "tempo de execução"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depois de definida a ["planta baixa" do tipo (classe)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100814/101) você não pode mudar nada dentro dele. Então todo o modelo é fixo por todo o tempo de execução, cada campo, campo método, cada detalhe de definição do tipo não pode ser mudado. E todos os objetos que sejam instanciados partindo deste modelo sempre serão idênticos, é garantido.

Isso se contrapõe às linguagens dinâmicas onde é possível mudar a composição do modelo ou de objetos em específico durante a execução, o que dá flexibilidade, mas há perda de performance e robustez no código, já que é preciso todo um tratamento para lidar com esta situação, otimizações não são possíveis porque não sabe o que vai encontrar ali, e a todo momento pode ter uma surpresa.

A herança em Java é algo conceitual, ocorre no modelo e não no objeto, então você herda um modelo em outro que está modelando agora.

Se mudar o código e recompilar a herança ou toda composição de cada classe pode se montar diferente e a **próxima** execução terá as diferenças inclusas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).