# Referência estática dando erro ao acessar

Tags: java, métodos-estáticos

O meu código está dando um erro de referência estática, o que essa informação quer dizer?

```
  public class inicio {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

               System.out.println(soma(2,2));

       }
       public int soma(int n,int m){
             int num = n+m;
             return num;
       } 
 }
```

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Olá Lodi. Está dando -cannot make a static referência to the type .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você criou um método de instância chamado `soma()`. Ele é de instância porque esse é o padrão dos métodos de classes em Java. Então para usá-lo tem que ser através de um objeto criado, não pode simplesmente chamar o método de forma direta.

O método `main()` é estático, portanto ao contrário do outro método ele pertence à [classe e não ao objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Só existe um para a aplicação. Quando chama `soma()` nele sem estar atrelado a um objeto espera-se que ele também seja estático, e é isto que está faltando no outro método para funcionar:

```
public static int soma(int n, int m) {
    return n + m;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Static2.java).

É possível em vez disso criar uma instância desse tipo e aí chamar o método por este objeto, mas isto não faz sentido neste caso, sem estado um objeto não deveria ser criado.

Eu estudaria orientação a objeto antes de prosseguir. Não vai no chute que não aprende. Na verdade antes de aprender OOP eu aprenderia quase todas as outras coisas sobre programação, elas são mais importante que isso. Por enquanto saiba que o básico quando vai usar um método ele deve ser estático para se comportar como uma função e não um método.

Comment: @Maneiro, Obrigado.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger sim, funciona, mas não faz sentido fazer isto.