# Erro de compilação sobre referência de elemento não estático

Tags: java, classes, herança, java-8, visibilidade

```
public abstract class Teste {
    public static final Teste IMPLEMENTACAO_1 = new Teste() {
        @Override
        public void executar() {
            teste1();
        }
    };

    public static final Teste IMPLEMENTACAO_2 = new Teste() {
        @Override
        public void executar() {
            teste2();
        }
    };

    public static final Teste IMPLEMENTACAO_3 = new Teste() {
        @Override
        public void executar() {
            // Non-static method 'teste3()' cannot be referenced from a static context
            teste3();
        }
    };

    public abstract void executar();

    public void teste1() {}

    protected void teste2() {}

    private void teste3() {}
}
```

A classe acima, na `IMPLEMENTACAO_3`, é lançado um erro de compilação dizendo:

> elemento não estático não pode ser referenciado por um elemento estático

Porém, as três implementações usam essencialmente o mesmo código, diferindo apenas pelo modificador de acesso das funções que são chamadas.

Qual o por quê de apenas a função privada gerar esse erro? O que o modificador de acesso influencia nisso? No meu entendimento as três funções deveriam dar problema.

Comment: O erro exibido é confuso pois o "this" está implícito. Se você modificar todas as chamadas de teste para conter "this.", aparece o erro real: "The method teste3() from the type Teste is not visible", que é bem menos confuso.

Comment: Então, para mim não ficou muito claro por que está dando o erro que dá. Para mim deveria dar que o método não é visível.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, não é visível mesmo. Pois é criada uma "classe invisível" em algum lugar, e por ela estar fora da classe Teste, não pode acessar o método privado.

Comment: @Piovezan **Palpite**: esse parece ser um *corner case* estranho, não sei. De qualquer forma, se o método for `private static void teste3()`, aí o código compila (isso porque ao ser `static` as regras de visibilidade nas subclasses não valem mais), então no código acima o compilador deve considerar que vc tentou chamar um método que deveria ser estático mas não é, já que está em um contexto estático.

Comment: Por outro lado, se vc tentar criar uma subclasse (em vez de um campo estático), aí dá o erro de "cannot find symbol", conforme esperado: https://repl.it/repls/AlertCoralMethods#Teste.java - então meu palpite é que o compilador tenta primeiro verificar o contexto estático, e depois verifica as regras de visibilidade. A não ser, é claro, que vc chamasse explicitamente por `this.teste3()`, como já disseram acima, pois aí deixa claro que não quer chamar o método estático, e aí dá o erro de que o método não é visível.

Comment: @hkotsubo Ah, agora entendi o que significa "conter `this.` nas chamadas de `teste()`". Não tinha entendido, tinha achado que era pra acrescentar no parâmetro. E valeu pela explicação :)

Comment: @Piovezan Se quiser, vc pode olhar no código fonte do compilador pra ter certeza: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/ :-) (não, eu não olhei)

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado pela dica, mas não vou olhar não. Bom saber que existe, mas prefiro não cometer esses _corner cases_. Se é pra classe filha enxergar, não deve ser private. E melhor não abusar de herança, como você bem sabe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No momento que está instanciando a classe `Teste` no campo estático precisa criar a implementação do método abstrato e é isso que faz corretamente, afinal classes abstratas não podem ser instanciadas diretamente. Então o que acontece quando cria essa instância?

Há uma herança da classe `Teste` para uma classe temporária (anônima) para permitir a extensão da classe e implementação do método que não estava implementado. É meio esquisito, mas é assim que funciona, na prática não está instanciando bem `Teste` e sim uma classe derivada dela, ainda que no código isso não seja visível.

Também é esquisito porque está instanciado dentro da própria classe, mas membros estáticos são assim mesmo, eles estão ali quase por acaso, poderia estar em outros lugares, eles não pertencem ao objeto, eles não enxergam os membros do objeto de forma direta. Pense nele como se estivesse em outro lugar porque dá no mesmo.

Se quiser saber mais leia [Referência estática dando erro ao acessar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365986/101) e [Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17015/101).

Então no momento que chama `teste1()` tudo funciona porque você tem acesso a um método público de qualquer lugar da aplicação, desde que um objeto desse tipo esteja instanciado ele pode ser chamado, é assim com todos membros públicos.

Não há problema em chamar `teste2()` que é protegido. Esse método não pode ser chamado de qualquer lugar, só pode ser chamado em uma classe que seja derivada da classe base, ou seja, tem que ser derivada de `Teste`. E de fato é isso que acontece conforme expliquei no segundo parágrafo, você tem ali uma classe invisível derivada de `Teste`.

Já `teste3()` não pode ser chamado porque ele é privado, ou seja, ele só pode ser chamado dentro de um objeto da classe `Teste`. Não pode chamar nem mesmo de uma derivada dela que é o caso que criou ali. E dá o erro.

Pode estar pensando: "mas está dentro de `Teste`". Está dentro da classe, não do objeto, membros estáticos não fazem parte do objeto, por acaso está tudo junto, mas é como se fosse algo separado, então não funciona.

Leia [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Também [Qual a diferença entre variáveis de instância de classe, automáticas (locais) e de duração estática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257817/101).

Se acredita que deveria funcionar você deveria justificar porque deveria. Se não conseguir justificar então não poderia. Nada deve funcionar sem justificativa.

O exemplo é bom e ajuda no aprendizado de muita gente, pena que o site já não tem atraído mais pessoas que querem saber disso, mas a pergunta é um alento.

Comment: Eu não sabia sobre essa parte de criar uma "classe invisível", se bem que imaginei que teria algo secreto por debaixo dos panos... Muito obrigado pela explicação, ajudou demais.
Se não for pedir demais, poderia me dar uma dica de como fazer essa classe funcionar corretamente? Eu preciso que a função seja privada e pelo que eu vejo, a única maneira de fazer isso, é tornando ela estática. Está correto, ou tem alguma outra forma?

Comment: Nessa não tem jeito porque ela é artificial, em uma real poderia ter uma solução diferente que só pode ser pensada com o caso real. Ser privado ou estático são coisas diferentes.