# Erro: non-static method getAtivo() cannot be referenced from a static context no java

Tags: java, método, static

Eu estou tentando acessar o  método da classe Projeto `getAtivo` pela classe Curso no método `getNumeroProjetosAtivos`, mas quando tento acessar aparece o erro:

> Non-static method getAtivo() cannot be referenced from a static
> context.

Aqui a classe `Curso`

```
package ProvaLogica;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Curso {
    private String nome;
    private String sigla;
    private List<Projeto> projetos;


    public Curso(String nome, String sigla ) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sigla = sigla;
        this.projetos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void adicionarProjeto(Projeto projeto) {
        this.projetos.add(projeto);
    }

    public int getNumeroProjetos() {
        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < projetos.size(); i++) {
            soma = i + soma;
        }
        return soma;
    }

    public List<Projeto> getProjetosAtivos() {
        return this.projetos;

    }



    public  int getNumeroProjetosAtivos() {

        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= projetos.size(); i++) {
            if (Projeto.getAtivo () ) {
                soma++;
            }
        }
        return soma;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }
}
```

E aqui a classe Projeto

```
package ProvaLogica;

import java.util.List; import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Projeto {
    private String titulo;
    private boolean ativo;
    private Curso curso;
    private List<Pessoa> participantes;

    public Projeto (String titulo, boolean ativo, Curso curso ){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.ativo = ativo;
        this.curso = curso;
        this.participantes = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public String getTitulo(){
        return this.titulo;
    }




    public  boolean getAtivo(){
        return this.ativo;
    }
    public void adicionarParticipante(Pessoa pessoa){
        try{
            if (this.ativo == true)
                this.participantes.add(pessoa);
        }catch(RuntimeException erro1){
                System.out.println("Não é possível adicionar participante em um projeto não ativo");
            }

    }

    public int getNumeroParticipantes(){
        int soma= 0;
        for (int i=0 ; i<participantes.size(); i++){
            soma = i+soma;
        }
        return soma;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+be+referenced+from+a+static

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Referência estática dando erro ao acessar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365986/refer%c3%aancia-est%c3%a1tica-dando-erro-ao-acessar)

Answer (score -1):

Há um erro de lógica em sua implementação.
Estou supondo que o problema está na implementação do método `getNumeroProjetosAtivos`:

Veja que está tentando acessar um método de classe, porém deveria usar um método de instância de uma classe para acessar o método `getAtivo()`. Por isto o compilador está dando um erro de que o método `getAtivo()` não é estático, porque na verdade você tentou acessar aquele método diretamente através da implementação da classe `Projeto`.

Para saber a causa raiz do erro é necessário entender o que é um método estático, métodos estáticos pertencem a uma classe e são acessados diretamente sem a necessidade da instância de uma classe. Eu posso utilizá-lo diretamente fazendo uma chamada através da classe (que é o que tentou fazer).

Os métodos estáticos são frequentemente métodos utilitários encontrados nas classes `System`, `Wrapper` e `Collections`. Os métodos estáticos são criados quando o estado do objeto não tem efeito em seu comportamento porque dependem apenas de seus parâmetros de entrada.

Você pode saber mais sobre métodos estáticos acessando a [`documentação`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Desta forma, uma maneira de corrigir o problema seria acessando o método `getAtivo()` de uma instância da classe `Produto`.

Outro erro está na maneira que está iterando sobre os elementos desta coleção. Neste trecho:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= projetos.size(); i++) {
```

Da maneira que declarou as variáveis ocorrerá um erro `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, então será necessário corrigir a maneira que itera sobre a coleção. Para isso basta remover o `'='`.

O código final ficará desta forma:

```
public  int getNumeroProjetosAtivos() {
int soma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < projetos.size(); i++) {
    if (projetos.get(i).getAtivo () ) {
       soma++;
    }
}
return soma;
```

Aprenda mais sobre o método [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) do tipo *List*.