# Chamar uma classe dentro de outra

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu estou usando classes dentro de classes e queria saber se posso instanciar a segunda classe no construtor da primeira.Funciona e não notei nenhum problema ligado a desempenho, porém queria me certificar se está certo assim. Ex.:

```
class A{}
```

vou chamar ela na classe B

```
use A

class B{
public $classeA;

function __construct(){
$this->$classeA = new A();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está usando classe dentro de classe. Veja [o que é uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Você está criando uma classe que tem um campo e que na construção dela está inicializando este campo com uma instância de outra classe, só isto. Só se chama métodos, classes não podem ser chamadas. Entenda o conceito correto para continuar.

Perfeitamente normal e comum fazer isto.

Como demonstração de mecanismo está tudo ok, o exemplo é bom porque não expõe outros detalhes não necessários a este problema. Mas entenda que uma classe real não pode ser assim. As pessoas querem programar orientado a objeto sem entender o que isto significa e precisa pensar numa quantidade enorme de coisas, e quase sempre fazem errado, começando por usar um paradigma para gerenciar complexidade em uma linguagem de *script*. Então esse é o menor dos problemas do que pode dar errado aí. Os erros mais graves que vai cometer não é na instanciação, é na formulação geral da classe.

Comment: ok,obrigado pela resposta!! na verdade eu acredito ter formulado mal a pergunta...eu quero é usar métodos de outras classes dentro de uma nova classe...mesmo assim, vou dar uma olhada no link sim!! obrigado mais uma vez!!!

Comment: Eu só posso responder o que você perguntou.