# Por que um método que usa polimorfismo está sendo chamado no lugar de outro em caso de herança?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, método, herança, polimorfismo

Alguém poderia explicar porque a saída do programa é:

> Primata andando Mamífero ouvindo **Homem vendo**.

Não deveria ser?:

> Primata andando Mamífero ouvindo **Mamífero vendo**

[image: Classes]

Ano: 2019 Banca: IDECAN Órgão: IF-PB Prova: IDECAN - 2019 - IF-PB - Professor - Informática

Comment: A pergunta está muito confusa, falando coisas que não fazem sentido, sem deixa\r claro sobre o que está falando em cada ponto tornando ambíguo. Escrever um texto melhor será um bom exercício que ajudará entender e se ainda tiver uma dúvida relevante fica mais fácil para darmos uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @Maniero, Eu gostaria de saber porque a saída do programa é Primata andando Mamífero ouvindo Homem vendo. O que não consegui compreender foi o  motivo do copilador utilizar   o método ouvir() da classe Homem e não da classe Mamifero.

Comment: Em nenhum momento da pergunta você fala de saída. O que é copilador? O que ele tem a ver com isso? Se for o que eu tô pensando ele nada tem a ver com o problema, por isso está confuso. Talvez esteja usando termos incorretos e aí está aprendendo tudo errado, por isso pode estar tendo dificuldade de fazer a pergunta. Edite a pergunta dando o máximo de detalhes possível. Bem bem no problema antes, isto já ajudará entender o problema. tente usar a técnica do pato de borracha https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_com_Pato_de_Borracha, ajuda muito enter o seu próprio problema.

Comment: Poste o código como texto em vez de imagem. Eu já reabri porque agora dá para entender a pergunta, mas seria melhor o texto pra gente poder responder melhor demonstrando.

Comment: A saída que você está dizendo, é impossível, pois vc não tem nenhum método pai para chamar essa cadeia de métodos. Aparentemente, você só tem uma estrutura de métodos, e neste caso não teria nenhuma saída possível.

Comment: O `main` chama tudo, é fato..., porém ele está amarrado em um método, pai que é construído dentro dele mesmo, não sei se funciona assim... o main precisa existir antes de fazer qualquer instância...

Comment: @IvanFerrer é verdade, ficou tão confuso que eu comi bola, dá pra responder. Mas está tudo ok: https://ideone.com/Buc4xM.

Comment: Mas isso é polimorfismo, pelo que sei, o java faz isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É assim mesmo que funciona o polimorfismo. Quando você criou um objeto do tipo `Homem` ele tenta executar os métodos deste objeto, certo? E ele achou o `ver()`. Se um método não existe neste tipo o que ele faz? Ele procura o método no tipo ascendente dele, no caso no `Primata`, e acha o `andar()`, certo? E se ainda não achar procura no próximo ascendente, por isso no `Mamifero` acha o `ouvir()`, certo? Se ainda for procurar algum outro procurará em `Object` já que todas classes tem como ascendente final a classe `Object`, e finalmente se o método não for encontrado em lugar algum dá erro de compilação. Até aí tudo bem?

Então quando chama o `m.andar()` está chamando o método de `Primata`. E você reconhece que está certo imprimir o conteúdo dele. Em `andar()`está chamando `ouvir()`, então ele vai procurar o método na classe mais específica possível novamente. No caso só a `Mamifero` tem esse método, e o executará. Que por sua vez chama o método `ver()`. Qual é o método que ele chamará? Novamente **o método da classe mais específica possível** que neste caso é a `Homem`. Sempre vai procurar na classe mais específica possível para depois tentar nas demais subindo um nível de cada vez. Acho que é aqui que está pensando errado.

Por alguma razão acha que ele deve usar o método mais próximo possível. Por alguma razão está pensando em classes como composição e não como herança, que é um erro comum. Quando tem herança você deve esquecer as demais classes, deve pensar apenas na classe mais específica como se fosse completa. E ela é completa se pegar os métodos que não existem nela das outras classes. O método não está escrito ali nela, mas o método existe nela, ele só está tomando emprestado de outra classe, mas o objeto é aquele mesmo.

Não é bem assim, mas podemos pensar na classe desta forma:

```
class Homem {
    protected void ouvir() {
        System.out.print("Mamifero ouvindo ");
        ver();
    }
    protected void andar() {
        System.out.print("Primata andando ");
        ouvir();
    }
    protected void ver() {
        System.out.print("Homem vendo ");
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Homem m = new Homem();
        m.andar();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/PolimorphismExample.java).

Note que ela foi composta pelo método que já existia nela, e os demais métodos das outras classes, dando preferência para a classe mais específica sempre. De fato tem linguagem que faz a herança (se é que pode chamar assim) exatamente desta forma criando uma classe completa, só não é tão comum. O que linguagens como Java faz é manter uma tabela virtual de chamada de métodos onde tem os endereços dos métodos, sendo que o endereço que é colocado ali é sempre o do mais específico possível.

Classes são como modelos, provavelmente está pensando nelas como objetos e por isso faz confusão. Veja [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Quem manda é o objeto concreto que foi criado, ele é que determinará quem será chamado, não o que está nos outros tipos, não o que está no tipo declarado, por isso quem manda neste casos é `Homem` e não `Mamifero`.

Sem o polimorfismo seria tudo chamado do `Mamifero`, mas aí nem o `Primata` entraria na jogada. Sem o polimorfismo quem mandaria é o tipo declarado, no caso `Mamifero` e ele tem todos os métodos necessários. Mesmo que não tivesse todos não teria nada que pudesse fazer não só porque não tem o polimorfismo, mas também porque por que ele não pode ter consciência de classes criadas partindo dele, então a classe seria abst4rata e não poderia ser instanciada.

De qualquer forma este exemplo mostra bem como funciona o mecanismo, mas costuma desensinar como se programa verdadeiramente orientado a objeto, é uma pena que usam tanto este tipo de exemplo.