# Utilizar variável de outra classe em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho a seguinte classe;

```
class Banco {

constructor (agencia, conta, saldo) {
    
    this.agencia = agencia
    this.conta = conta
    this.saldo = saldo


exibir () {

    console.log(this.saldo)

 }

}
```

Digamos que eu queira utilizar a variável agencia em outra classe

```
class novoBanco extends Banco {

    exibir_agencia () {

        console.log(this.agencia)
        
    }

}
```

Nesse cenário acima, ainda preciso passar a variável como parâmetro da nova classe:

```
var exemplo0 = new Banco('1111-1', '22222-2', 0)
var exemplo = new novoBanco('1111-1')
exemplo.exibirAgencia()
```

Existe alguma forma de utilizar essa variável em outra classe sem precisar passar a mesma como parâmetro da nova classe?

Comment: Fazendo a correção em `"...Digamos que eu queira utilizar a variável agencia em outra classe..."` e `"...Existe alguma forma de utilizar essa variável em outra classe..."` o nome apropriado para essa estrutura destinada a acessar um dado hospedado numa classe ou objeto cujo é membro chama-se *Propriedade*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode usar o conceito de `getters` e `setters` para persistir os dados. de uma forma bem básica segue um exemplo abaixo usando classe estática. porém essa não é a melhor forma de fazer, mas só para mostrar que é possível, e perceba que não é mais estendida a Classe Banco.

Pois se vc extender `Banco` em `NovoBanco` a variavel `agencia` será zerada e retorna  `undefined` porque ao extender Banco, o construtor ira renovar os valores passado, se nada for informado o retorno será undefined.

```js
static class Foo { 
  public static agencia;

  static setAgencia(a) {
    self.agencia = a;
  }
 
  static getAgencia() {
    return self.agencia;
  }
}


class Banco {
   public data;
   
   constructor(agencia, conta, saldo ) {
        this.agencia = agencia;
        this.conta = conta;
        this.saldo = saldo; 
        this.data = Foo.setAgencia(this.agencia);
   }

   exibir() {
       console.log(this.saldo,Foo.getAgencia());
   }
}

class NovoBanco  {
  exibirAgencia() {
       console.log('Exibindo agencia\nGravada em new Banco():\n Angecia: ',Foo.getAgencia());
  }
}

var getConta = new Banco('1234-5', '22345', 0)
var exemplo = new NovoBanco();
exemplo.exibirAgencia();
```

Mas preste atenção nos conceitos de OOP. conforme o @Mineiro explicou.

Comment: Tentei mostrar o exemplo como typescript, mas não consegui adicionar a biblioteca, então segue o link com exemplo:  https://jsfiddle.net/3jL4cput/

Comment: Era exatamente isso, que eu queria. Obrigada !

Comment: Isso não faz o menor sentido, o código nem roda.

Comment: Tenta por aqui  https://jsfiddle.net/3jL4cput/

Comment: Esse roda, mas continua não fazendo sentido, quebrou o que deveria ser herança, criou uma classe tão sem sentido que nem nome útil tem.

Comment: Entendo, e sim, pois com herança não daria para fazer, pois como vc disse não faz sentido, a classe sem nome util foi uma forma de mostrar que dava para fazer o que foi questionado, e de uma forma clara que é possivel, não julgo niguem pela a forma de programar , so tento ajudar da melhor forma possivel, não quero prolongar este assunto, mas a unica coisa que não entendi é a  sua frustração.. olhe para o o lado bom, problema resolvido, como vai ser desenvolvido ja é outra questão os caminhos das pedras foram dado, e existem varias documentações para pesquisas.

Answer (score 2):

Há o erro conceitual, ou a pergunta não faz sentido. Tem outra classe, mas não tem outro objeto. Seria bom dar uma lida em [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101) para entender melhor.

A herança é uma forma de criar uma classe nova, ou seja, um modelo, sem precisar especificar tudo o que já existe na classe mãe e serve bem para a classe filha. Nada tem a ver com aproveitar dados no objeto, e de fato isso nem faz muito sentido. Talvez não tenha entendido bem como funciona a herança, porque usaria isso, inclusive dificilmente essa herança faz sentido de verdade, vou considerar que é só para testar o mecanismo.

Quando você está criando um objeto e guardando em `exemplo` só está lidando com a classe filha. mais ainda, não está passando variável alguma em lugar algum.

Estritamente não deveria passar só a agência. Na verdade um código coreto deveria testar isso e não aceitar se faltar os outros dados.

Parece haver outros erros conceituais mas não vou falar porque não tenho mais informações.

O código mais organizado (preste atenção aos detalhes)):

```js
class Banco {
    constructor(agencia, conta, saldo) {
        this.agencia = agencia;
        this.conta = conta;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    exibir() {
        console.log(this.saldo);
    }
}

class NovoBanco extends Banco {
    exibirAgencia() {
        console.log(this.agencia);
    }
}

var exemplo = new NovoBanco('1111-1');
exemplo.exibirAgencia();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/ExampleInheritance.js).

Comment: Então claro q o objeto seria criado para a 1º classe, já passando (agencia, conta e salario). A questão é como utilizar a variável "agencia", na classe "NovoBanco", sem precisar passar a mesma como parâmetro do objeto "exemplo", pois já seria passada como parâmetro do objeto da classe "Banco"

Comment: Nada disso faz sentido, e acho que não leu o que eu respondi, mesmo depois de eu te falar que todo seu conceito está errado você está repetindo ele.

Comment: A questão não é se está correto ou errado, o conceito eu entendi ! Só quero saber se é possível ou não, é simples ...

Comment: Se está errado, não pode. Você ainda não entendeu o que é programar, sugiro mudar a forma como quer fazer.

Comment: Ok, agradeço !!!