# Quem instancia, quem é instanciado e quem é a instância? Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, sou novo com programação orientada a objetos e programação no geral também, mas em um exemplo como o a seguir:

```
public class Profissao{
      public void trabalhar(){
            //trabalho...
      }
}
```

```
public class Ferreiro extends Profissao{
      public void consertarEspada(){
            //conserta...
      }
}
```

```
public class Programa{
      public static void main(String args[]){
            
            Profissao x = new Ferreiro;
      }
}
```

Eu sei que o objeto é x, mas ele é a instância? Se sim, é a instância de qual classe? Profissao ou Ferreiro?

E como um objeto do tipo Profissao pode receber atributos ou métodos da classe Ferreiro nesse caso? Se Ferreiro é uma subclasse de Profissao.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Também: [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/357)

Answer (score 4):

> Eu sei que o objeto é x, mas ele é a instância? Se sim, é a instância
> de qual classe? Profissao ou Ferreiro?

Eu não diria que `x` é o objeto, diria que `x` é uma referência para o objeto. O objeto é a região da memória que foi alocada pela chamada `new Ferreiro()`, logo uma instância da classe `Ferreiro`.

> E como um objeto do tipo Profissao pode receber atributos ou métodos
> da classe Ferreiro nesse caso? Se Ferreiro é uma subclasse de
> Profissao.

Um objeto do tipo `Profissao` não pode receber atributos nem executar métodos da classe `Ferreiro`, para o seu exemplo usando `x` seria necessário converter o tipo dele para `Ferreiro`

```
((Ferreiro)x).consertarEspada();
```

Seguindo seu exemplo ficaria complicado a utilização de várias classes derivadas de `Profissao` se cada uma dela tiver um método especifico, seria mais eficiente se a classe `Ferreiro` sobrescrevesse o método `trabalhar()`

```
public class Ferreiro extends Profissao{
      @Override
      public void trabalhar(){
            //conserta...
      }
}
```

Assim só chamando `x.trabalhar()` ele executaria a função de trabalho dele, independente de que tipo de objeto `x` está referenciando no momento.