# Diferença entre método e construtor?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, memória, método, construtor

Lendo as anotações de um amigo me deparei com a seguinte afirmação: "método não aloca espaço na memória". Esta afirmação está correta?

Talvez não seja a principal diferença entre eles mas, é correto afirmar que construtores alocam espaço na memória, enquanto os métodos, não?

Comment: +1 Ótima pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depende do contexto. Construtor é um método. Todo método ocupa um espaço na memória onde está **seu código**. Mas acho que não é bem isto que ele quer dizer.

O que provavelmente ele quis dizer é que o construtor aloca um espaço na memória para conter os dados do objeto que ele está construindo, e que o método nunca faz isto. Se for isto, sim, está certo, pelo menos, grosso modo, sim. A coisa pode ser um pouco mais complexa.

Se um método comum cria um novo objeto local ao método, ele está alocando espaço na memória, ou não? Indiretamente está. Se você achar que a execução de um método nunca aumentará o espaço ocupado na memória está cometendo um erro. Claro que diretamente a alocação estará sendo feita por um construtor deste objeto dentro do método que estamos falando.

Mas ainda podemos fazer outra análise. O construtor não aloca nada. Quem aloca é o gerenciador de memória da JVM, o construtor só preenche este espaço alocado com dados. Então estritamente falando, está errado. Mas dá para compreender o que a afirmação quer dizer, ainda que ela não seja precisa.

Provavelmente ele quer dizer que construtores criam objetos e os preenchem com dados (ainda que os [*defaults*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34685/101)) e os métodos comuns apenas manipulam os dados em objetos existentes.

Construtores possuem uma sintaxe própria para declará-los e para chamá-los.

Por serem usados na criação de objetos existem [implicações importantes quanto a herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45699/101).

Veja mais sobre o [uso de construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). [Quando eles são chamados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104512/101).

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89257/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resposta interessante. Lendo a apostila da Caelum (p. 79): "Um construtor não é um método. Algumas pessoas o chamam de um método especial, mas definitivamente não é, já que não possui retorno e só é chamado durante a construção do objeto". Fiquei com dúvida e achei que uma réplica nesta resposta seria suficiente. Meu entendimento era de que é um método, e tem um retorno: um objeto, com uma autorreferência this. Além disso, métodos void também não tem retorno, o que já invalidaria aquela afirmação. Faz sentido?