# Não entendo o que está acontecendo com essa classe controller, me explica?

Tags: collection, groovy

Não entendo mesmo, se alguém puder desenhar para mim, agradeço.

```
class DisciplinaController extends GenericController<Disciplina>{

    DisciplinaController() {
        super(Disciplina.class)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nessa classe estamos vendo o poder da herança associado ao uso de generics :D. A classe GenericController como o nome sugere, é um controller genérico. Isso significa que ela provavelmente tem métodos de inserção, remoção, atualização e listagem de elementos, que são básicos a diversos controllers.

Ao usar generics nela, o programador está declarando que "não importa" o tipo de elemento (ou classe de domínio) que será passado. Para qualquer tipo de elemento, o modo de agir será o mesmo. As classes que extendem o GenericController é que especificam o elemento que será tratado.

No caso do DisciplinaController, o elemento é um objeto da classe Disciplina.
O uso de generics é muito legal, pois permite essa simplificação no código, pois métodos genéricos são tratados na classe genérica. Somente métodos específicos necessitam ser tratados nas classes que herdam da classe genérica.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que fosse necessário criar um método listarDisciplinasInativas. Esse método seria implementado na classe DisciplinaController.

Por outro lado, vamos supor que precisemos de um controller básico para professores. Seria apenas necessário criar um controller ProfessorController do seguinte modo:

```
class ProfessorController extends GenericController<Professor>{
    ProfessorController() {
        super(Professor.class)
    }
}
```

Percebe como fica muito mais produtivo? Você detalha que quer trabalhar com a classe Professor, passando ela no construtor, e especificando o generics na herança (extends GenericController). Com isso, você já "ganha" a implementação dos métodos básicos (inserir, remover, atualizar, listas) que estejam implementados na classe GenericController. Se não fosse pelo uso de generics, você teria que toda vez implementar os métodos básicos em todos os novos controllers:

```
class ProfessorController extends GenericController<Professor>{
    ProfessorController() {
        super(Professor.class)
    }
    void inserir() {/*Implementação do método*/}
    void listar() {/*Implementação do método*/}
    void remover() {/*Implementação do método*/}
}
```

Aumentando bastante o trabalho.

Comment: @AlineGonz faça outra pergunta. É outro assunto. Ainda mais agora que já aceitou a resposta

Answer (score 3):

Dá para dizer poucas coisas.

Está declarando a classe `DisciplinaController` que herda de `GenericController<Disciplina>` que é uma classe que realmente implementa o mecanismo de controlador que será usado nesta classe. Esta é uma classe [genérica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101), ou seja, ela permite trabalhar com diversos tipos de dados verificado e substituído de forma estática. Isto quer dizer que em alguns lugares dela é preciso dizer qual é o tipo de dado que vai ser manipulado e na classe, ao invés de colocar um tipo fixo, é colocado um tipo genérico na sua escrita, que é uma espécie de super variável, então quando for usar a classe ela será usada com este tipo que está sendo passado no `<>`.

Depois há a declaração do [método construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104707/101). Sei disto porque tem o mesmo nome da classe. Ele será usado para inicializar os dados iniciais da classe.

Dentro dele é chamado o construtor da classe que herdou (`super()` é uma palavra-chave da linguagem que tem esse propósito), afinal precisa inicializar os dados da  outra classe. Está passando a classe `Disciplina` como parâmetro para ele. No caso não está inicializando nada na própria classe, talvez não precise mesmo, mas não dá para saber só com este trecho.

Não sei se é a melhor forma de ir aprendendo, mas está explicado. Se tiver dúvidas mais específicas vai perguntando.

Comment: Acho que entendi...