# Métodos e construtores são a mesma coisa?

Tags: java, método, construtor, jvm

Algumas fontes dizem que construtor é um tipo especial de método, enquanto outras dizem que construtores não são métodos. Há quem diga, também, que apesar de serem diferentes a JVM os trata da mesma forma. Afinal, um construtor é um tipo de método ou são coisas diferentes apenas com alguns aspectos em comum?

Comment: Quero salientar que esta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104707/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-m%C3%A9todo-e-construtor também feita por mim questiona apenas a diferença de um aspecto entre as estruturas (métodos e construtores).

Comment: Se você já fez a outra pergunta, não entendi o propósito dessa

Comment: Cite as fontes que dizem essas coisas. O entendimento pode estar errado, ou as fontes podem não ser confiáveis.

Comment: Como eu falei a outra questiona um aspecto entre as duas, trecho da outra pergunta:  "Talvez não seja a principal diferença entre eles mas, é correto afirmar que construtores alocam espaço na memória, enquanto os métodos, não?". Nesta pergunto se um método e um construtor são a mesma coisa, vejo uma diferença entre as perguntas. Posso estar enganado mas acho que seja válido fazer esta.

Comment: @bigown agora tenho que sair, mais tarde edito a pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, construtores são métodos.

E pode-se falar que são "especiais", pois eles apenas podem ser chamados no ato da instância de uma classe.

Pode-se aplicar as mesmas seguranças de acessos, como public, private, protected.

Comment: O construtor também é chamado ao invocar `super()` ou `this()`. Também não pode ser `synchronized`

Comment: Exato @PabloAlmeida, todos os construtores são `síncronos`, e nunca podem ser `assíncronos`.