# Construtor de construtor?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor, sobrecarga

Gostaria de entender por que esta classe tem **dois construtores** e por que um deles está com tudo dentro do mesmo *this* e não separado como na outra. Isso muda algo?

Construtor normal:

```
public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha, double saldo) {
    Random gerador = new Random();
    this.numeroDaConta = gerador.nextInt(9000)+1000;
    this.correntista = correntista;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}
```

Construtor do construtor:

```
public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha) {
    this(correntista, senha, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) não é tão [diferente de um método comum](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104707/101). Assim como métodos podem ser [sobrecarregados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101), construtores também podem. Então você pode ter métodos com o mesmo nome e [assinaturas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Isso faz com que ele seja outro método. Isto é útil porque cada um pode ter uma conveniência.

No seu caso o primeiro seria um construtor completo que faz tudo o que precisa. O segundo apenas delega para o primeiro como fazer a construção. Então você não precisa passar o saldo se ele é um valor padrão, chama sem ele e o construtor secundário se encarrega de passar o saldo para você.

Isso não é necessário em linguagens que possuem argumentos com valor padrão, o que não é o caso de Java, pelo menos ainda.

Existe uma sintaxe especial para mostrar que está chamando um construtor e não um método qualquer. É chamar o método `this`. Dessa forma o compilador pode tratar de forma diferente. Então o construtor secundário não constrói o objeto, o primário o fará. Mas é ele que entregará o resultado, se for ele que foi invocado na instanciação do objeto.

Essa sintaxe é necessária porque pode existir métodos não construtores com o mesmo nome da classe.

Note que [o `this` no outro construtor é usado para desambiguar a variável local ou parâmetro do atributo do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154186/101). Então não está tudo dentro do mesmo `this`, é a mesma sintaxe para mecanismos diferentes.

```
this(correntista, senha, 0);
```

nesse caso é o mesmo que

```
Conta(correntista, senha, 0);
```

que não pode ser chamado dentro de um construtor de forma correta sempre (pode haver ambiguidade).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Constructor.java).

Alguém pensaria que pode ter feito o mesmo código nos dois construtores. Mas isso viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e pode criar dificuldade de manutenção. Isso não é para poupar linha de código, tem finalidade semântica importante. Não há ganho de tempo nisso.

Entenda que isso até é um tipo de polimorfismo, mas normalmente chamamos de sobrecarga, porque o entendimento de polimorfismo normalmente remete a outra coisa. Essa terminologia é um pouco ambígua, sobrecarga não é.

Não vou comentar sobre os outros problemas deste método que não é foco da pergunta e para um exercício está ok.

Comment: Então toda a vez que eu chamo o construtor "simples", eu estou passando as informações dele para o construtor "composto"?

Comment: Neste exemplo sim, mas não necessariamente.

Comment: Como eu posso saber que o construtor simples está passando para o composto ou não? (onde fica evidente isso?)

Comment: Não sei, porque essa terminologia é errada, eu não sei o que quer dizer.  Com uma premissa errada, fica complicado responder qualquer coisa.

Comment: "CONSTRUTOR SIMPLES":
`public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha) {
    this(correntista, senha, 0);
}`
"CONSTRUTOR COMPOSTO":
`public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha, double saldo) {
    Random gerador = new Random();
    this.numeroDaConta = gerador.nextInt(9000)+1000;
    this.correntista = correntista;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.saldo = saldo;
}`

Comment: Não tem nada de simples ou composto aí, ambos são construtores, são métodos. Um deles é curto e o outro é maior. Quer saber que está passando o que?

Comment: Tá difícil... Um exemplo: se eu deletar o construtor maior, o menor vai funcionar normalmente? Caso não, quero saber se as informações capturadas para o construtor curto, estão indo para o longo.

Comment: Não, se você apaga alguma coisa, essa coisa deixa de funcionar, se algo depende dela, deixa de funcionar também. Sugiro começar pelo começo, entender cada conceito, de forma estruturada, aí o entendimento das coisas virá facilmente. A questão aí nem é de construtor. Pesquise sobre method overloading (sobrecarga de métodos).

Answer (score 2):

Olá, utilizar vários métodos construtores te possibilita construir objetos de muitas maneiras. Dessa forma, uma vez que você declarou esse construtor:

```
public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha, double saldo) {
  Random gerador = new Random();
  this.numeroDaConta = gerador.nextInt(9000)+1000;
  this.correntista = correntista;
  this.senha = senha;
  this.saldo = saldo;
}
```

E você sinta a necessidade de criar objetos do tipo Conta sem passar um saldo, você pode declarar um construtor que só recebe como argumento um objeto correntista e a senha:

```
public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha) {
    this(correntista, senha, 0);
}
```

Dessa forma, uma vez que tenha um método construtor mais "completo" que já faz todas as atribuições necessárias, basta chamar esse construtor mais "completo" dentro do novo construtor, passando como argumento o atributo que o novo construtor não recebe, nesse caso o saldo.

Quando você chama no segundo método construtor:

```
this(correntista, senha, 0);
```

Indiretamente você está chamando o primeiro método construtor que recebe três argumentos. Como o responsável pelas atribuições dos parâmetros aos atributos do objetivo é o primeiro construtor, o segundo método construtor apenas usa um this, e passa a responsabilidade toda para o primeiro método construtor.

Comment: Caso eu adicione mais um atributo na assinatura do "construtor composto", eu terei que adicionar no "construtor simples"?

Comment: Sim, de forma que o construtor simples use a assinatura correta do construtor composto ao chamá-lo. Perceba também que se você sentir falta de um atributo na classe você pode criar um novo construtor simples que faz atribuição do novo atributo e, depois, chama o construtor composto para fazer a atribuição do restante dos atributos. Assim você sempre estará a economizar escrita de código.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
Isso que foi feito no código acima chama-se polimorfismo. Essa é uma sobrecarga de métodos.

Bom digamos que no código acima você queira criar uma conta, e essa conta pode ser tanto criada sem saldo inicial ou com saldo inicial. Ao criar uma conta com saldo inicial:

```
Conta novaConta = new Conta(new Correntista(),"teste",30.30);
```

Ao chamar o `new Conta` será invocada a classe *Conta* e dentro dela sera chamado um construtor. Nesse momento será executado o método que mais se adeque com os parâmetros da chamada. Neste caso o primeiro código que você postou.

No caso de criar uma nova conta sem o saldo, o programador poderia ter feito o método assim:

```
public Conta(Correntista correntista, String senha) {
    Random gerador = new Random();
    this.numeroDaConta = gerador.nextInt(9000)+1000;
    this.correntista = correntista;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.saldo = 0;
}
```

Mas para poupar linha de código e tempo o que ele faz é, ele chama o outro construtor com argumento que tem saldo através do `this` e coloca um saldo inicial 0. Assim poupando código e tempo.

Não muda nada, só foi feito para poupar tempo e adequar a chamada, você pode ler um pouco mais sobre polimorfismo [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/12/06/c_poli1.htm)

Comment: Então se eu quiser, criar o método com esse `this`, ele ainda sim vai passar as informações para o construtor superior?